# How can I install the Beautiful Soup module on the Mac?

Tags: python, macos, module, installation

I read this without finding the solution: http://docs.python.org/install/index.html

Comment: pip install beautifulsoup4

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the current right way to do this is by `pip` like Pramod comments

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

because of last changes in Python, see discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).
This was not so in the past.

Comment: I have no idea why, but doing `pip install beautifulsoup`, without the final `4`, install some beautifulsoup package that is not found in import.

Comment: @srodriguex Do: *pip search beautifulsoup* and you see which packages they have there. No *bautifulsoup* but *beautifulSoup*.

Comment: I think some users may need sudo else may get the following error "OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info'"

Answer (score 80):

The "normal" way is to:

- Go to the Beautiful Soup web site, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/
- Download the package
- Unpack it
- In a Terminal window, `cd` to the resulting directory
- Type `python setup.py install`

Another solution is to use `easy_install`. Go to http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall), install the package using the instructions on that page, and then type, in a Terminal window:

```
easy_install BeautifulSoup4
# for older v3:
# easy_install BeautifulSoup
```

`easy_install` will take care of downloading, unpacking, building, and installing the package. The advantage to using `easy_install` is that it knows how to search for many different Python packages, because it queries the [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/) registry. Thus, once you have `easy_install` on your machine, you install many, many different third-party packages simply by one command at a shell.

Comment: After you are done installing, use this import command for BeautifulSoup4.0 : "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"

Comment: Installing on Mac? Throw in the `sudo ` before `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 14):

Brian beat me too it, but since I already have the transcript:

[easy_install](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall)

```
aaron@ares ~$ sudo easy_install BeautifulSoup
Searching for BeautifulSoup
Best match: BeautifulSoup 3.0.7a
Processing BeautifulSoup-3.0.7a-py2.5.egg
BeautifulSoup 3.0.7a is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.0.7a-py2.5.egg
Processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup
Finished processing dependencies for BeautifulSoup
```

.. or the normal boring way:

```
aaron@ares ~/Downloads$ curl http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/download/BeautifulSoup.tar.gz > bs.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 71460  100 71460    0     0  84034      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  111k

aaron@ares ~/Downloads$ tar -xzvf bs.tar.gz 
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoup.py
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoup.py.3.diff
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoupTests.py
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoupTests.py.3.diff
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/CHANGELOG
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/README
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/setup.py
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/testall.sh
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/to3.sh
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/PKG-INFO
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoup.pyc
BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/BeautifulSoupTests.pyc

aaron@ares ~/Downloads$ cd BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1/

aaron@ares ~/Downloads/BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1$ sudo python setup.py install
running install
<... snip ...>
```

Comment: You don't need root access to install BeautifulSoup

Comment: I tried with easy_install and then I just tried to test at the terminal but I still get the following error.

Comment: this works great! i did not have write privileges in my python2.7/site-packages. So I had to do "super user do" or sudo ...

Answer (score 4):

Download the package and unpack it. In Terminal, go to the package's directory and type

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo yum remove python-beautifulsoup
```

OR

```
sudo easy_install -m BeautifulSoup
```

can remove old version 3

Answer (score -2):

On advice from http://for-ref-only.blogspot.de/2012/08/installing-beautifulsoup-for-python-3.html, I used the Windows command prompt with:

```
C:\Python\Scripts\easy_install c:\Python\BeautifulSoup\beautifulsoup4-4.3.1
```

where BeautifulSoup\beautifulsoup4-4.3.1 is the downloaded and extracted beautifulsoup4-4.3.1.tar file.
It works.