# Python - suds - no module

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I've installed Python 2.7.1, setuptools and suds 0.4.

When running my script, I'm having the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test.py", line 5, in 
    from suds.client import Client       # suds soap client
ImportError: No module named suds.client

It looks like Python can't find the suds library. But I can't understand why ...

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Also, it looks like suds isn't maintained. What are you using to call your web services using Python?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/pypm/suds/

Comment: Probably it has nothing to do with your problem but consider using pip instead of easy_install. Here are some arguments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Answer (score 15):

Sounds like suds is not actually installed.

Since you have setuptools, try:

```
easy_install https://fedorahosted.org/releases/s/u/suds/python-suds-0.4.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yes, correct. Suds was not installed, I forgot to update this topic. To install studs (and I suppose other modules), you have to be outside the Python folder, otherwise it won't work ... Thanks Ashy for your response anyway.

Comment: @Olivier if the Ashy's answer worked for you then you should accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

For ease of installation and [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889297/how-to-debug-error-creating-list-item-in-sharepoint-via-updatelistitems-soap-api/21395165#21395165) [fixing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6794466/819417), i put the `suds` folder from [suds-jurko](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.6) (and `ntlm` folder from [python-ntlm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-ntlm)) next to the `main.py` file of my new maintenance tool. That way a minimum of specialist knowledge is required to install it:

1. Unzip `Tool.zip` to `C:\`
2. Run `C:\Tool\Tool.bat`

I could probably put the required Python interpreter in there, as well. That's how [many](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/category/packaging/) Python "compilers" work.