# How do I update virtualenv on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, ubuntu-11.04

I have installed virtualenv version 1.4.9 and the latest version is 1.6.1. How do I update to version 1.6.1. Do I have to uninstall version 1.4.9? If so, how do I uninstall it?

Comment: @Blender If I remember correct, I used the command 'sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv', then I tried to install version 1.6.1 through easy_install and I think it only sort of re-install version 1.4.9. When I run 'virtualenv --version' I get 1.4.9

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Latest version is 1.6.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)
use `sudo pip install virtualenv` it will upgrade incase you are using`1.4.x` version.
It advised to use `pip` over `easy_install` [look here for the reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)

Comment: Probably should be `sudo pip install -U virtualenv` to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

no, you don't. newer installed version of virtualenv automatics override older installed version.

if I remember currently, use this to install:

```
sudo easy_install virtualenv==1.6.1
```