# Why does pip fail when installing local egg repository?

Tags: python, local, pip, egg

I am working on Windows 7.I have created a python egg using distutils. Now I try to install this egg in a virtual environment using pip 1.0.2 using the following command:

Then I create a virtual environment *myVirtualEnv* I activate it using activate.bat then execute the following command:

`pip install path_to_my_local_folder#eggName`

This creates a copy of my egg in my *myVirtualEnv\build* directory but I have the following error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: path_of_my_virtualEnv\build\PyEqdR\setup.py

Do you know why pip is looking for the setup.py file. Should I include it in the egg ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/other-tools.html#pip-compared-to-easy-install

> pip doesn’t do everything that easy_install does. Specifically:
>
> It cannot install from eggs. It only installs from source.

Comment: Related: [Why use pip over easy_install?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3220404/95735)

Comment: Is this no longer the case with newer `pip`?

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this page and since I had the same exact problem, I thought to post the solution that worked for me.

This is an issue with the older versions of pip. My version of `pip` was `1.5.4`. I was not able to find the first version of `pip` that was able to do it but the current version `6.0.6` does the job.

To update to latest `pip` version, simply run the following command:

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Needless to say if you want this to only take effect inside your virtual environment, run it inside the environment. Otherwise, run it globally.

Comment: @oktay I get the same error even after updating the pip. Could you help