# How to host an python egg file and install with easy_install or pip?

Tags: python, nginx

I have a server that produces egg files every time source code is updated. The egg files are generic base modules  stored in a folder named "dist"

There are a number of egg files inside dist eg:

xxx-3.1.0-py3.5

yyy-3.1.0-py3.5.egg

.....

We are a team of developers who are individually working on different projects and we rely on the above core python models.

I have configured my nginx to list the directory using autoindex on;

My issue is i an unable to use easy_install

```
easy_install -H None -f https://xxx.co.th/version/ xxx-3.1.0-py3.5.egg
```

Am i missing some some files ? i do not want to host the setup.py files , i actually generated these egg files based on setup.py

Any solution is highly appreciated

Comment: Nowadays, you should target only `pip` and not `easy_install` (That's assuming that `pip` works for your project -- there are few corner cases). You should also use `wheel` format and not `egg`. Please consider hosting your releases on `pypi` (unless your project is closed source that is).

Answer (score 0):

pip doesn’t do everything that easy_install does. Specifically:

It cannot install from eggs. It only installs from source.

[see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7490955/4070498)

Comment: Really? Then what are all the `egg` reference about on https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/