# MySQLdb for Python 2.7 (Ubuntu)

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, mysql-python

After I installed MySQLdb by

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

I can import and use it when I use Python 2.6, but not 2.7. (ImportError: No module named MySQLdb)

I think that apt-get install MySQLdb in version 2.6, but I don't know how to make python 2.7 work with it. Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want system-wide installation for python2.7 you should use easy_install-2.7. Install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (or [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute)) for python 2.7, then type:

> easy_install-2.7 mysql-python

**Update:**

Or just

> sudo apt-get install python2.7-mysqldb

Notice without adding sudo you'd not be able to make the changes.

Comment: [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/) is the successor to easy_install and a bit [more modern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).

Comment: @miku Personally I prefer distribute. It's better then pip for me.

Comment: AFAIK that requires having python2.7-dev and all the compiler stuff, plus libmysql, otherwise you won't be able to compile it. but I have installed this on both python 2.6 and 2.7 with apt-get only, trouble is I don't remember how, if anything was needed for it. IIRC installing python-mysqldb installed it for both python versions.

Comment: I can't install mysql-python by pip, here is the error message:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17350105/error
Please help... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @MaksymPolshcha, but I got "E: Couldn't find package python2.7-mysqldb"

Comment: @陳碩甫 To install using pip you have to install python2.7-dev and mysql-dev (or libmysql-dev depending on your OS)

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. I installed mysql-python successfully after installed python2.7-dev. You save my life. Thank you really!!

Comment: Danke @MaksymPolshcha "sudo apt-get install python2.7-mysqldb" has worked for me.