# What is best option from pip, pythontools or easy-install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am looking for the best option to keep my Python upgraded and to install new packages. I know there was previous discussion like this: [Why use pip over easy_install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) but they often quite old.

The problem is: I have ubuntu 12.04 at home and Windows 7 at work, would like to keep both of them on the same (newest) version level.

In ubuntu I found that repository contains often old version so I use different procedures to install new packages. I also found that pip installs new version, but did not check other options. In windows I try to install from provided .exe files which sometimes is difficult, and to have ipython working I had to install pythontools. Over the internet I see a lot of opinion about the subject, and advocates to different tools.

Is there a way to keep to different computers (ubuntu/windows) upgraded on the same level and what is the best choice.

I am looking for a constructive opinions like: if you use ... then you don't have to add paths manually but you need to clean downloaded files, or this ... will work perfectly on linux but for the reason ... not on windows.

I would like to use it in ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Windows.  I think people like pip because it does dependencies better than easy_install.  But I don't know enough about that to say more.  Using virtualenv is a great choice in that it keeps your projects versions.   You can also to pip freeze > requirements.txt to get a list of packages you installed within virtual env.  This file can then be used to download those versions in another virtualenv.  virtualenv installs its own local pip

Answer (score 1):

If someone has problem with installation basic packages under windows this http://viziblr.com/news/2012/4/21/step-by-step-installing-pandas-on-windows-7-from-pypi-with-e.html gives good help. It works well in windows, although does it does not resolve the issue.