# Python Module Repository

Tags: python

I was looking for something similar to perl's `Dumper` functionality in python. So after googling I found one which serves me well @ https://gist.github.com/1071857#file_dumper.pyamazon

So I downloaded and installed it and it works fine.

But then I came accross PyPI: http://pypi.python.org/pypi which looks like CPAN equivalent for python.

So I searched for the Dumper module there and I could not find it there. I was hoping that this seems like a very basic module and should have been listed in PyPI.

So my question is, if I have to install a python module, then should I search in PyPI first and if i do not find then look other places on google?

OR is there any other Python Module repository apart from PyPI?

I am learning python and hence this question.

thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using pip, `pip search package_name` would help you do the same as searching on the web interface provided by PyPi.

Once located, installing a python package is of course as easy as

```
pip install package_name
```

Some python libraries may be in development stage and may not directly be available on PyPi OR you may want a specific commit has (git) of that library and if you can find that library's source on `github.com` or on `bitbucket.com` for example, you can do

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/the/repo/url.git#egg=package_name
```

And regarding your question about perl Dumper, perl's Dumper has two main uses iirc -

- data persistence
- debugging and inspecting objects.

As far as I know, there's no exact equivalent of perl's Dumper in python.

However, I use `pickle` for data persistence.

And `pprint` is useful for visually inspecting objects/debug.

Both of which are standard, built-in modules in Python. There's no necessity for 3rd party libraries for these functionalities.

If you  want to use what is here - https://gist.github.com/1071857#file_dumper.pyamazon.

What you need to do is to copy the code and place it in a local file in your project directory.  You can name the file something like `pydumper.py`. Or any name you prefer really, but end it with suffix `.py`.

In your project, you can import the functions and classes defined in `pydumper.py` by doing

```
from pydumper import *
```

or if you want to be specific (which is preferred. it's better to be explicit about what you are importing.)

```
from pydumper import Dumper
```

and you can start using the Dumper class in your own code.

Comment: I never bothered what perl's Dumper does behind the curtains. I always used it to "visualize" deep nested hashes and arrays and it had been a life Savior. so I was looking for something similar in python to "visualize" deep nested lists/dictionaries and i found in above mentioned github link. again, I am indifferent to what it does behind the curtains.

Comment: You can use the code (which is not packaged and uploaded to pypi) using what I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like [easy_install from setuptools?](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) I might have misunderstood your question as I don't use perl.

From the `Scripts` directory in the python installation directory ("c:/python27/Scripts" on my machine), you can install modules from the command line like so:

```
easy_install modulename
```

Makes life alot easier if you set the Scripts directory to your PATH variable.

Comment: I am looking for a place where i can find python modules. In perl, CPAN is a one stop shop for perl modules. Similarly, in python, I found PyPi for python. But a very basic module like Dumper is not listed in PyPI and I could find it on github made me wonder is PyPI the right place for me to look in case I need to install a python module.

Comment: You should avoid using `easy_install` as far as possible. There are some libraries that need to be installed with `easy_install` but for most situations, `pip` is the right choice.

Comment: @CalvinCheng - Yeah I've realised that after answering this question. Related here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install