# Python - no module named setuptools

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to install modules on an alternate version of Python (3.3.0) I have installed on my Mac (OS X 10.7.4). The new version of Python runs OK in the IDLE and also in Terminal:

However, trying to install something relatively trivial like NumPy only installs in the old pre-installed version of Python on my Mac (2.7.1).

Executing this:

```
$ python3.3 easy_install numpy
```

Gives me this error message:

> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'easy_install': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I then read that creating a virtual environment is the way to go, so I tried that:

```
$ mkvirtualenv python=python3.3 foo
```

It returned this error:

> -bash: mkvirtualenv: command not found

So, I clearly don't have that installed correctly, either (`virtualenv-1.8.4`).

There is probably lots more homework that I need to do, but I don't really have any intention of using 2.7 ever again, just Python 3 so I don't need to go back and forth. At the same time I know that I need to keep the old version of Python on my Mac for whatever reason, so I don't intend to delete it. Any suggestions for what I'm missing would be very helpful.

Comment: Note that the command is `virtualenv`, without the leading `mk`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
easy_install numpy
```

easy_install is a shell script, not a python script.

Comment: Note: [you shouldn't use easy_install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install).

Comment: I agree with you. It is better to use pip. I just answer the question, who want to use easy_install. Thanks.

Comment: This returns: error: can't create or remove files in install directory

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong command. Instead of:

```
$ python3.3 easy_install numpy
```

you want:

```
$ easy_install3 numpy
```

or even more specific:

```
$ easy_install-3.3 numpy
```

[But you shouldn't be using `easy_install` in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install):

```
$ pip3 install numpy
```

or more specific than `pip3`:

```
$ pip-3.3 install numpy
```

---

If you look deeper, you'll see that both `pip3` and `pip-3.3` are the same:

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 1.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)
$ pip-3.3 --version
pip 1.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg (python 3.3)
```

and both `easy_install3` and `easy_install-3.3` are the same:

```
$ easy_install3 --version
distribute 0.6.32
$ easy_install-3.3 --version
distribute 0.6.32
```

Comment: $ easy_install3 numpy returns error: can't create or remove files in install directory. Same thing with easy_install-3.3...

Comment: That probably means that you need root privileges: prefix the command with `sudo`. Also, `pip`: `pip3 install numpy` or `sudo pip3 install numpy`.

Comment: Try running `ls $(which easy_install)*`, see what you get. I'm inclined to believe that this is some kind of PATH issue, as from your last comment, `easy_install` returned something. This command should show all of the `easy_install` binaries you have.

Comment: `zsh: command not found: easy_install3`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Anaconda from Enthought. It had all the plugins and such that I needed. Thanks for everyone's suggestions and help! :)