# Python mechanize module not found

Tags: python, module, mechanize

My python version is: Python 2.7
I did an easy_install mechanize then I tried running a script and I'm getting this:

```
File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
import mechanize
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

If you need any other information let me know.

Comment: Can you find `mechanize` in `site-packages`?

Comment: How could I try that? I'm sorry but I'm very new to Python.

Comment: `C:\Python<version>\Lib\site-packages`

Comment: I also recommend using `pip` over `easy_install` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Comment: site-packages is empty. Also when running pip I get: "ImportError: cannot import name walk_packages"

Comment: What's your OS?  It may affect pip (also, what version pip are you using? `pip.exe --version`

Comment: CentOS 5. I'm using pip-2.4

Comment: So you're using pip for python 2.4 on python 2.7? I'd assume so since the latest `pip` version is 1.2.1

Comment: Apparently I had Python 2.4 and Python 2.7 installed simultanously.

Comment: Run `pip` from python 2.7's scripts directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in case pip or easy_install, for whatever reason, aren't working:

Download the source code from http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/m/mechanize/mechanize-0.2.5.tar.gz

Unzip the package, go to the command line, change into the folder that was extracted and type:

```
python setup.py install
```

If you're on Linux/Mac, you may need to type the following:

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

Comment: Thanks this was the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Would like to add something for some future users:

In case some of the users get the error "No module named '_version'"
Mechanize however doesn't support Python 3 so you should install a Python 2.x release (the latest available is 2.7.3), install the mechanize package there and then retry running your script.