# How do I install Pyramid on Python 3.3 Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, pyramid

I have been having a heck of a time trying to install Pyramid on my Python 3.3 Windows 7 x64 machine.  I have done the following from scratch with no luck. I have double checked all of my install files:

- Install python 3.3
- Install Python for Windows extensions
- Install Distribute 0.6.34 (latest)
- easy_install Virtualenv
- Activated my new virtualenv
- easy_install pyramid

I followed [Pyramid's install guide](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/install.html#index-7) here while substituting Python32 for Python33:

`easy_install pyramid` finishes and puts the following egg files in my `venv\liv\site-packages` folder:

- mako-0.7.3-py3.3.egg
- pastedeploy-1.5.0-py3.3.egg
- pyramid-1.4-py3.3.egg
- repoze.lru-0.6-py3.3.egg
- translationstring-1.1-py3.3.egg
- venusian-1.0a7-py3.3.egg
- webob-1.2.3-py3.3.egg
- zope.deprecation-4.0.2-py3.3.egg
- zope.interface-4.0.3-py3.3-win-amd64.egg

However the actual folders are still in the egg folders and not have been copied to the site-packages folder.  Should they be?  Seems like an incomplete installation to me because the code can't even see the import modules from those egg folders.
I try to run [this test code](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/configuration.html) and I get import errors.

As a test, I moved all the folders in the egg folders up one level so they are now in the site-packages folder.  I run the test code and I get different import errors.  In fact, I have done this whole install process at least 10 times today from scratch.  The import errors can be different.  It's almost like the pyramid install is getting corrupted or incomplete.  However, the install always finishes with no errors.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Consider using pip : pip install pyramid (you can use easy_install to install pip).

Comment: @Ketouem Why pip? Docs only mention `easy_install`.

Comment: There's a good topic on easy_install vs pip on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install

Comment: btw on pylonsproject website they mention the usage of pip for the installation http://www.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/download

Answer (score 1):

I've used pip for python and everything went fine, all dependencies were installed and

```
import pyramid
```

did not throw any error afterwards.

Have a look at http://pastebin.com/bdv1SK7k.

Note: to install pip you need to, ironically, call easy_install pip

Comment: Yes, using pip installed pyramid fine.  it was easy_install that was messing everything up.  I actually thought of using pip when I was in bed.  I glad you guys concur :)