# Any tool installing external python libraries( like MySQLdb)

Tags: python, package, package-managers

Is there any tool for installing external python modules from a central repository( like cpan for perl). I installed MySQLdb module using yum.

Comment: [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use pip over easy\_install?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out pip and the python package index: https://pypi.python.org/pypi

You can package up your own modules and upload them to a private pip server as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pip - tool for managing Python Packages (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).