# Can't install python egg due to directory permissions

Tags: python, linux, easy-install, egg

I'm still getting familiar with python and python eggs so sorry if this is a stupid question.  I want to know why easy_install appears to install the egg for the whole server to use rather than just locally for the account that tried to install it.

I created a simple helloworld module/egg and tried to install it on a server I have an account on.  However, the account doesn't have root access (it's a tester's account).  I get a "Permission denied" error message when installing it.  When installing the module, it is trying to install to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site_packages/blah/blah/blah.  It's pretty clear it's b/c I don't have root access to write to this location.

```
easy_install hello-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

On my laptop (my account has root access), I can run the cmd above and see the module is installed by running 'pip freeze'.  The slight difference is that Anaconda is running/installed on my laptop and seemed to be doing the package management for me.

So back to my original question; how does easy_install install eggs that we create ourselves?  I was hoping/assuming it would install the module in my tester's account and not to /usr/local/lib/blha/blah/blah for all users to use/access.  Is this an incorrect assumption?  If this is incorrect thinking, how would someone install a module/egg where the account doesn't have root access?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se per [easy_install or pip as a limited user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912804/easy-install-or-pip-as-a-limited-user) you'll want to use the `--prefix` option to `easy_install` and/or `-d` or `-s`.

I believe you could do something as simple as:

```
easy_install --prefix=$HOME hello-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) which allows you to create multiple virtual environments for Python, each with its own set of libraries.

Just create a virtualenv and then you can then install your module within it without requiring write access to the system Python installation.

There is a tutorial here: http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/, but simply install virtualenv then:

```
$ cd $HOME
$ virtualenv test
$ cd test
$ source bin/activate
$ easy_install /path/to/hello-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

The package should be installed into `~/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages`