# Python pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, trac

I am trying to install Trac on windows (64-bit) and i have followed all the installation guidelines. 
But when i try to run the trac standalone server using tracd, i get this error:

```
PS C:\Python27\Scripts> .\tracd.exe --port 8000 D:\TracEnv\
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\tracd-script.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2940, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 635, in _build_master
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 943, in require
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 829, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'trac==1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

I have installed trac and it is present in the site package directory where i installed python.

```
-a---         4/15/2016   4:25 PM    1894048 trac-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

So why is it not able to find trac?
i do not have admin access on this PC. I do not know python, i just want to install and learn how to use Trac.

Comment: How did you install Trac? Did you install using `pip` or `easy_install`, or did you use the exe installer? If you used the exe installer, make sure to use the [amd64 installer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Trac/1.0.10), to match your Python version.

Comment: I used easy_install. It works fine when i have admin access. But i can only get temporary admin access.

Comment: You might want to at [installing to you user directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912804/easy-install-or-pip-as-a-limited-user).