# How to install pandas from pip on windows cmd?

Tags: python, windows, pandas, cmd, pip

I am trying to install pandas using pip to run some pandas-based Python programs. I already installed pip. I tried googling and SO'ing but didn't find a solution to this error. Can somebody share your inputs on this?

```
C:\> pip install pandas
```

Error:

```
pip is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and the output of `pip install pandas`?

Comment: pls check my edited post...

Comment: @Teja Apart from Pandas there are some modules which can't be downloaded from pip and need to be downloaded from other resources for that you can have a look on my answer

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Since both `pip` nor `python` commands are not installed along Python in Windows, you will need to use the Windows alternative `py`, which is included by default when you installed Python. Then you have the option to specify a general or specific version number after the `py` command.

```
C:\> py      -m pip install pandas  %= one of Python on the system =%
C:\> py -2   -m pip install pandas  %= one of Python 2 on the system =%
C:\> py -2.7 -m pip install pandas  %= only for Python 2.7 =%
C:\> py -3   -m pip install pandas  %= one of Python 3 on the system =%
C:\> py -3.6 -m pip install pandas  %= only for Python 3.6 =%
```

Alternatively, in order to get `pip` to work without `py -m` part, you will need to [add pip to the PATH environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23709194/6622817).

```
C:\> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\<path\to\python\folder>\Scripts"
```

Now you can run the following command as expected.

```
C:\> pip install pandas
```

---

## Troubleshooting:

---

#### Problem:

```
connection error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
```

#### Solution:

This is caused by your SSL certificate is unable to verify the host server. You can add pypi.python.org to the trusted host or specify an alternative SSL certificate. For more information, please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25981703/6622817). (Thanks to Anuj Varshney for suggesting this)

```
C:\> py -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org pip pandas
```

---

#### Problem:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

#### Solution:

This is a caused by when you don't [permission to modify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32167418/6622817) the Python site-package folders. You can avoid this with one of the following methods:

- Run Windows Command Prompt as administrator (thanks to DataGirl's suggestion) by:

  1. <kbd>[image: Windows-Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open run
  2. type in `cmd.exe` in the search box
  3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
  4. An alternative method for step 1-3 would be to manually locate cmd.exe, right click, then click Run as Administrator.
- Run pip in [user mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15912804/6622817) by adding `--user` option when installing with pip. Which typically install the package to the local %APPDATA% Python folder.

```
C:\> py -m pip install --user pandas
```

- Create a [virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43069780/6622817).

```
C:\> py -m venv c:\path\to\new\venv
C:\> <path\to\the\new\venv>\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Comment: How did you run it? And what is the actual error? If you used my command and succeed, pandas should be installed correctly

Comment: python filename.py

Comment: Do you have multiple pythons by any chance?

Comment: And you should run it using the same way as you used pip ie. `py -3 filename.py`

Comment: Thats a good catch.. I uninstalled 2.7 and just kept 3.5 on my pc

Comment: Yea because the default `python` is for the lowest version of python, you're welcome:)

Comment: I wanted to add a quick comment, in case this happens to anyone else.  I kept receiving an error message when I tried to install pandas that read Access Denied. (Sorry, I didn't think to copy it). I had to right click on the Command Prompt and run it as Administrator (even though I am the Administrator on my laptop) to get this to work.

Comment: The --user in the py -m install worked for me, exactly what i needed. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I've just done a fresh install of Python 3 from the Windows Store under Windows 11 and pip is installed by default. `pip install pandas` then installs the package without any issues.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the issue is because the environment variable is not set up to recognize pip as a valid command.

In general, the pip in Python is at this location:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts > pip
```

So all we need to do is go to Computer Name> Right Click > Advanced System Settings > Select Env Variable then under system variables > reach to Path> Edit path and add the Path by separating this path by putting a semicolon after the last path already was in the Env Variable.

Now run Python shell, and this should work.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Windows OS.

All you need to add the `pip.exe` path to the Environment Variables (Path).

Generally, you can find it under `..Python\Scripts folder.`

For me it is, `C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\`

Answer (score 2):

Reply to abccd and Question to anyone:

The command: `C:\Python34\Scripts>py -3 -m pip install pandas`
executed just fine.  Unfortunately, I can't import Pandas.

Directory path: `C:\users\myname\downloads\miniconda3\lib\site-packages`

My Question: How is it that Pandas' dependency packages(numpy, python-dateutil, pytz, six) also having the same above directory path are able to import just fine but Pandas does not?

```
import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I finally got Pandas reinstalled and imported with the help of the following web pages:                                                                                 *http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.pdf (Pages 403 and 404 of 2215 ... 2.2.2 Installing Pandas with Miniconda)
*https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/download.html                                 *https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html

After installing Miniconda, I created a new environment area to get Pandas reinstalled and imported.  This new environment included the current Python version 3.6.3.  I could not import Pandas using Python 3.4.4.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18933499)

Comment: I finally got Pandas reinstalled and imported with the help of the following web pages:

Answer (score 1):

Please Ensure you are using a virtualEnv this is how :

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname

source env/bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

on windows you have to add scripts exe in the CLASSPATH
in order to use pip command

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe
```

i suggest you to use MINGW he can gives you a better environment to work with python

Answer (score 1):

install pip, securely download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)

Then run the following:

> python get-pip.py

On Windows, to get Pandas running,follow the step given in following link

https://github.com/svaksha/PyData-Workshop-Sprint/wiki/windows-install-pandas

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user: 
make sure you added the script(dir) path to environment variables 
   C:\Python34\Scripts
for more how to set path [vist](https://youtu.be/p-Qqse-qmTM)

Answer (score 0):

pip install pandas
make sure, this is 'pandas' not 'panda'

If you are not able to access pip, then got to C:\Python37\Scripts and run pip.exe install pandas.

Alternatively, you can add C:\Python37\Scripts in the env variables for windows machines.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install pandas` or `python -m pip install pandas` in Python directory.