# How to create virtual env with python3

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am using **python 2.7** + **virtualenv version 1.10.1** for running myproject projects. Due to some other projects requirement I have to work with other version of python(**Python 3.5**) and **Django 1.9**. For this I have installed python in my user directory. Also I have dowloaded and installed virtualenv( **version - 15.1.0**) into my user directory. 
But whenever I am trying to create virtual env I am getting the below error

```
python virtualenv/virtualenv.py myproject
```

---

```
Using base prefix '/home/myuser/python3'
New python executable in /home/mount/myuser/project_python3/myproject/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /home/mount/myuser/project_python3/myproject/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/home/myuser/python3' (should be '/home/mount/myuser/project_python3/myproject')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong with this

Comment: It's not clear which Python you are using when you run `python virtualenv/virtualenv.py myproject`. Is `python` here your system Python (2.7) or your local Python (3.5)?

Comment: Did you use the correct pip, i.e. pip3, to install virtualenv version - 15.1.0?

Comment: I always find [these docs](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) helpful.

Comment: @Chris I  am using python3.5

Comment: @PM2Ring I have used the command python -m pip <virtualenv package>

Comment: Generally, `python` means Python 2, you need to use `python3` to refer to Python 3. Eg, `python3 -m pip install some_package`. But as others have said, it's better to use the `venv` module that is included in recent versions of Python 3.

Comment: @PM2Ring I have updated my bashrc_profile with path . That' the reason I am referring python :).  BTW I have installed the python 3.5.3 manually

Comment: Hmmm. That may not be wise if you have stuff that expects `python` to refer to Python 2, eg Python 2 scripts that aren't Python 3 compatible and which have a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line. A safer way is to make `python` an alias for `python3`.

Comment: @PM2Ring . Thanks for you suggestion. I have created an alias for python3 in my bashrc_profile

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573587/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrappe

Currently the number of "recommended methods" of creating virtual env's in python continues to increase; see also: (1) ["Pipenv is the officially recommended Python packaging tool from Python.org"](https://docs.pipenv.org/)  and (2) http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/ and (3)  [xkcd: Standards](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

In Python 3.6+, the pyvenv module is deprecated. Use the following one-liner instead:

```
python3 -m venv <myenvname>
```

This is the [recommended way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to create virtual environments by the Python community.

Answer (score 12):

**To create virtual env**

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv_name
```

> This will create new python executable in baseDirectory/bin/python3

**How to activate newely created Venv:**

```
cd baseDirectory/bin/  

source activate
```

Deactivate new venv

```
deactivate
```

**UPDATE_1**

This method has been depreciated as [The use of venv is now recommended for creating virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).
Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47822740/how-to-use-virtualenv-with-python3-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/60520679) link for updated answer

Comment: Worth to remember is what people are saying below: since Python version 3.3, there is no need to install and use `virtualenv`, as `venv` exists as an embedded module. Btw. creating alias for `source venv/bin/activate` is much more efficient than cd and activating it.

Answer (score 6):

Python already ships with its builtin "virtualenv" called `venv` since version 3.3.  You no longer need to install or download the `virtualenv` scripts for Python 3.3+.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Check that your installation provided the `pyvenv` command that should take care of creating the "virtualenv".  Arguments are similar to the classic virtualenv project.

```
$ pyvenv --help
usage: venv [-h] [--system-site-packages] [--symlinks | --copies] [--clear]
            [--upgrade] [--without-pip]
            ENV_DIR [ENV_DIR ...]

Creates virtual Python environments in one or more target directories.

positional arguments:
  ENV_DIR               A directory to create the environment in.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --system-site-packages
                        Give the virtual environment access to the system
                        site-packages dir.
  --symlinks            Try to use symlinks rather than copies, when symlinks
                        are not the default for the platform.
  --copies              Try to use copies rather than symlinks, even when
                        symlinks are the default for the platform.
  --clear               Delete the contents of the environment directory if it
                        already exists, before environment creation.
  --upgrade             Upgrade the environment directory to use this version
                        of Python, assuming Python has been upgraded in-place.
  --without-pip         Skips installing or upgrading pip in the virtual
                        environment (pip is bootstrapped by default)

Once an environment has been created, you may wish to activate it, e.g. by
sourcing an activate script in its bin directory.
```

Comment: This script is deprecated in Python 3.6+, although the module still exists. The recommended use is: ``python3 -m venv <myenvname>``

Comment: @user73657 I am using python 3.5 . But if i run the command pyenv its saying command not found

Comment: @user73657 pyenv is not available in 3.5.3

Comment: @Anish, the script isn't `pyenv` but _`pyvenv`_.

Comment: Oh sorry . let me try

Answer (score 3):

**virtualenv** is the tool of choice for Python 2, while **venv** handles the task in Python 3.

Yet you can create the virtual environment for Python 3 using any of them.

### Using `venv`

`python3 -m venv virtualenvname`

Command Syntax:

`/path/to/python3 -m venv /path/to/directory/virtual_env_name`

### Using `virtualenv`

`virtualenv -p python3 virtualenvname`

Command Syntax:

`virtualenv -p /path/to/python3 /path/to/directory/virtual_env_name`

### Activate the virtual environment

On Linux, Unix or MacOS, using the terminal or bash shell:

`source /path/to/venv/bin/activate`

e.g.  `source virtualenvname/bin/activate`

On Unix or MacOS, using the csh shell:

`source /path/to/venv/bin/activate.csh`

On Unix or MacOS, using the fish shell:

`source /path/to/venv/bin/activate.fish`

On Windows using the Command Prompt:

`path\to\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`

On Windows using PowerShell:

`path\to\venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

### Deactivating the virtual environment

On Linux, Unix or MacOS, using the terminal or bash shell:

`deactivate`

On Windows using the Command Prompt:

`path\to\venv\Scripts\deactivate.bat`

On Windows using PowerShell:

`deactivate`

This answer is for those who may use a different OS.

Answer (score 2):

To create a virtual environment, go to your project’s directory and run the following command. This will create a new virtual environment in a local folder named .venv:

> python3 -m venv .venv

Activate a virtual environment

> source .venv/bin/activate

To confirm the virtual environment is activated, check the location of your Python interpreter:

> which python

To deactivate a virtual environment

> deactivate

See more here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/

Answer (score 1):

Since the launch of Python version 3.3, there has been no need to download the `virtualenv` package separately as it comes built-in in Python.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to gain complete insights on it.

Test the installation of virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv --version
```

Usage:

> 1.Creating a virtual environment:
>   $ virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 ./virtual_env_name
>
> 2.For enabling it, use the following command:
>   $ source ./virtual_env_name/bin/activate
>
> 3.For disabling the virtual environment and get back to working with the local environment:
>   $ deactivate
>
> For listing down the packages in the virtual environment, use the
>   following command:
>   $ pip3 list

Answer (score 0):

I install it using the command (for Python 3.x),

```
$ python3 -m venv env
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a virtual environment in python3:

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 virtualenvname`

After creating the virtual environment, we need to activate it using the below command:

`source virtualenvname/bin/activate`

to deactivate use the below command:

`deactivate`

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows.

1. manually download and install the version of python you want from the [official site](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)
2. after installation, search "python" to locate the folder, so you can identify the path
3. get the path of the **.exe**  (for example: C:\Users\Path\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe)
4. Inside the folder of which you want to create the environment...start bash or VSCode terminal, or whatever command prompt, type **[python .exe path] -m venv [env name]** like this:

   C:/Users/Path/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe -m venv myenv
5. (Note that you have to change forward slash to backward slash for the path on step 4)
6. Activate the environment like so:

   source myenv/Scripts/activate

Answer (score 0):

***CREATE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT:***

**For Python 3 version:**

**Command:** `python3 -m venv [environment_name]`

**Example:** `python3 -m venv my_virtual_environment`

**For Python 2 version:**

**Command:** `python -m [environment_name]`

**Example:** `python -m venv my_virtual_environment`

***ACTIVATE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT IN LINUX:***

**Go to the virtual environment directory then open terminal.**

**Command:** `source [environment_name]/bin/activate`

**Example:** `source my_virtual_environment/bin/activate`

***ACTIVATE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT IN WINDOWS:***

**Go to the virtual environment directory then open cmd.**

**Command:** `[environment_name]\Scripts\activate`

**Example:** `my_virtual_environment\Scripts\activate`

Answer (score -1):

Install virtualenvwrapper on top of virtualenv to simplify things.
Follow the blog to install in easy steps: [virtualenvwrapper](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenvwrapper)

Steps to create it:

1. mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3
2. Install packages using - pip install package_name
3. `workon` - activates the virtualenv, `deactivate` - deactivates the viirtualenv

Comment: How will adding a wrapper around `virtualenv` help if `virtualenv` itself isn't working?

Comment: This is a repeated answer. This is also an incorrect answer. virtualenv is deprecated, this is a wrapper around virtualenv