# Updating python version on a Mac

Tags: python, macos-catalina, biopython

I just bought a MacBook Pro and the preinstalled version of python is 2.7.x and I was attempting to install `biopython` but that requires python 3.6 and higher. 
I then downloaded the latest python which is 3.8.5.
When I run terminal to install `biopython` I get an error saying that `biopython` requires version above 3.6 to run and that version 2.7 is downloaded.
How can I make it so it recognizes version 3.8.5 or any version above 3.6?

Answer (score 2):

For your terminal to run python 3.x run

```
python3 <your command>
```

and similarly for pip

```
pip3 install <package name>
```

Or you can just make a virtual environment. Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069780/how-to-create-virtual-env-with-python3).

Answer (score 2):

Symlink python to python3 in `/usr/bin`. If you ever need to access python 2.7 run python2.7.

```
brew install python3
brew link
sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 # skip this step if /usr/bin/python2.7 already exists
ln -s /usr/local/bin/python $(which python3) # note /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin
```

Note:

Use `brew` (ubiquitous open source MacOS package manager) to install python3. This will make maintaining package installs, versions and updates a lot simpler.

References:

Brew: https://brew.sh

Comment: Here he have already installed python3.x. And so what he have to is update the path for python3.

Comment: @HarshitRuwali You installed python, but there's no easy way to update it and other packages that you install in the future without using a package manager. But yes, you need to update the symlink in /usr/bin to point to python3.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked docs for biopython https://biopython.org/wiki/Download and they ask you to run

```
pip install biopython
```

So what you have to ensure is that your `pip` uses Python 3+ like here

```
> pip -V
pip 20.2.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: you can't run a pip command like that on MacOS without being in a virtual environment. You have to use the `python3 -m pip install <package-name>` or you can use the outdated pip3 wrapper.