# How do I install virtualenv in Python 3.10.2 and activate it for a telegram bot?

Tags: python, environment-variables, virtual

I tried some guides that I found but nothing works. I need this virtual env for a telegram bot. I| use Visual studio code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a virtualenv, and why should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41972261/what-is-a-virtualenv-and-why-should-i-use-one)

Comment: "I tried some guides that I found but nothing works." We can better help you solve the specific problems you encountered if you tell us what they are. [Edit] your question to include more details such as what steps you took and what happened at each step. If there is an error, I suggest googling that error to see what other people already did to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create virtual env with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069780/how-to-create-virtual-env-with-python3)

Answer (score 0):

How to install virtualenv:
Install pip first

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then install virtualenv using pip3

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Now create a virtual environment

```
virtualenv venv
```

**you can use any name insted of venv**

You can also use a Python interpreter of your choice

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

Active your virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

Using fish shell:

```
source venv/bin/activate.fish
```

To deactivate:

```
deactivate
```

Create virtualenv using Python3

```
virtualenv -p python3 myenv
```

Instead of using virtualenv you can use this command in Python3

```
python3 -m venv myenv
```

Comment: Of course, this is for if he's using Ubuntu or another Debian based based distribution.

Comment: I created the env with the python3 -m venv myenv command that you gave me. how can I now activate it?

Comment: @scorpio11 what is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Install**. To create a virtual environment, use the following command, where `.venv` is the name of the environment folder:

```
python -m venv .venv
```

2. **Activate**. When you create a new virtual environment, a prompt will be displayed to allow you to select it for the workspace.

This will add the path to the Python interpreter from the new virtual environment to your workspace settings. That environment will then be used when installing packages and running code through the Python extension.

You can switch environments at any time at the bottom left corner of **VS Code** window or using the **Python: Select Interpreter** command from the **Command Palette** `(Ctrl+Shift+P)`.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like your problem is activating the virtual environment.

```
source env/bin/activate
```

or just type `activate` in your terminal.

If you are using windows try:-

```
env\Scripts\activate.bat
```