# I Can't Create a Virtual environment For Django

Tags: python, django

I wanted to create a Virtual Environment for My Django Project But whenever i tried to install pipenv it doesn't work. Please

I want to install and create a Virtual environment.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Can you describe your technical environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create virtual env with python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069780/how-to-create-virtual-env-with-python3)

Comment: anosha_rehen : I have attach a photo with it the thing i get that " 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and want Python 3, this should do it:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-venv, python3, python-is-python3, python3-pip
python -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
```

But you would have an easier time getting good answers if you included a little more information in your question, e.g. OS and error message.

Comment: I got this type of message " 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```

and then make the environment using `python3 -m venv env_name`

Comment: Thaks a Bunch it work's :)