# Python import pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am following this tutorial online called [leanpython.org](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics), and was following the tutorial about the pandas dataframe. I ran the code below and it worked fine in the code editor on their website, but when i run it on my text editor (Brackets), it doesn't work. Is the code wrong? or is the website just out dated or something?

```
import pandas as pd

dict = { "word": ["hi", "bye", "apple", "orange", "tree", "google"], "numOfLetters": ["2", "3", "5", "6", "4", "6"]}

brics = pd.DataFrame(dict)

print(brics)
```

Comment: add error in your question

Comment: Do I need to install pandas dataframe or something.

Comment: Did you check this [How to install pandas from pip on windows cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42907331/6194097) question?

Comment: there were no errors. it just exits right after i run the code.

Comment: first install pandas using pip install pandas

Comment: Did you install [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) in your machine?

Comment: I just installed pandas and it worked. thanks.

Comment: How can it be that there where no errors on `import pandas` if pandas was not installed???