# How to import the pandas library?

Tags: python, pandas

I had installed Python 3 on my laptop running Windows 10. I was trying to import pandas library so that I can read and edit Excel files for a project. However, it is giving an error.

The code I use is the standard:

```
import pandas as pd
```

I get a `Traceback, ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907331/how-to-install-pandas-from-pip-on-windows-cmd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pandas from pip on windows cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907331/how-to-install-pandas-from-pip-on-windows-cmd)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html

Answer (score 1):

```
pip uninstall pandas    
pip install pandas
```

Run these commands.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, it doesn't work.

Comment: Why dosnt it work? Do you not have pip installed? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Here : https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/
this should help you understand how to install a new package

Comment: Nope, I was trying to work with Python 3 that I installed directly

Answer (score -1):

I would go into the anaconda navigator and see if you can import it from there.
Cheers,
Kyle

Comment: Thank you, Kyle. However, I do not use Anaconda. I am using Python 3 by directly installing it on Windows 10