# Extract numbers from the mixed string and conditionally do some calculations afterwards in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Straight to the "issue".

I got one "simple" task to try to solve in Power BI > Power Query, where I got one mixed column supposed to be an Amount column, with lot of different number/text/special chars combinations, which have to be firstly converted into number format and then conditionally calculated if there is "brutto (no case sensitive) in general", then divide that value with 1.5 and if there is CHF value divide that value with 1.9. The rest of data, like errors, #values or even nulls can be removed. Expected column is shown as OnlyAmountNr and in my Query steps.

This is short example of my data:

```
| Amount          | OnlyAmountNr |
|-----------------|--------------|
| Brutto ? 468384 | 468384       |
| 965-            | 965          |
| 703623 brutto   | 703623       |
| 654-? Netto     | 654          |
| ?1738           | 1738         |
| CHF     12800.0 | 12800        |
| #VALUE!         | -            |
| 89989           | 89989        |
| 0               | 0            |
```

What I used, at least to my knowledge are these steps,which might be too long for this kind of task:

```
     let
        Quelle = Sql.Databases("ukTest123.database.windows.net"),
        CSD_DE_RawData = Quelle{[Name="CSD_DE_RawData"]}[Data],
        money_ASD_Applications = 
        CSD_DE_RawData{[Schema="money",Item="ASD_Applications"]}[Data],
        EXTRACT_SPECIAL_CHARS = Table.AddColumn(money_ASD_Applications, "Custom1", each Text.Select([Amount],{"A".."z","0".."9"})),
        EXTRACT_NUMBERS = Table.AddColumn(EXTRACT_SPECIAL_CHARS, "Custom2", each Text.Select([Custom1],{"a".."z","A".."Z"})),
        EXTRACT_T_F = Table.AddColumn(EXTRACT_NUMBERS, "Boolean", each if Text.Contains([Custom1], "brutto") then true else if Text.Contains([Custom1], "Brutto") then true else false),
        EXTRACT_TEXT = Table.AddColumn(EXTRACT_T_F, "OnlyAmountNr", each Text.Remove([Custom1],Text.ToList(Text.Remove([Custom1],{"0".."9"})))),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(EXTRACT_TEXT,{{"OnlyAmountNr", type number}}),
        #"CALCULATION_MwSt." = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "MwSt._CH_DE", each if [OnlyAmountNr]> 1 and [Boolean]= true then ([OnlyAmountNr]/1.199) else if [OnlyAmountNr]>1 and [Custom2]="CHF" then ([OnlyAmountNr]/1.077) else null)
     in
        #"CALCULATION_MwSt."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a custom function implementing Regular Expressions to extract the number.
Then added a custom column to implement the logic.

*I used the logic in your question, and not the logic in your code.  In your code you have different divisors. Also, I was not sure about handling numbers where Amount did not contain `brutto` (case insensitive) or `CHF`, so, as per your question statement, I set them to null, but that is easily remedied if that is not what you really intend (just change `else null` to `else n` in the custom column formula)*

***Custom Function**
Rename fnRegexExtract*

```
//Rename fnRegexExtract

let   fx=(text,regex)=>
    Web.Page(
        "<script>
            var x='"&text&"';
            var y=new RegExp('"&regex&"');
            var b=x.match(y);
            document.write(b);
        </script>")[Data]{0}[Children]{0}[Children]{1}[Text]{0}

in
fx
```

***Main Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Amount", type text}}),
    
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Number Only", each let 
        n =Number.From(fnRegexExtract([Amount], "\\d+")),
        result = 
          if Text.Contains([Amount],"brutto",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then n/1.5
              else if Text.Contains([Amount],"CHF") then n/1.9 
              else null 
            in result, type number)
in
    #"Invoked Custom Function"
```

[image]

***Or, after changing `else null` to `else n`***
[image]

Comment: Nice Ron. You may want to devide the value in case of CHF though. Another small point is the regular pattern. You currently are not capturing potential decimals am I right? With given example the single decimal pressent is zero anyway, but in case it's `1.11` you may want to capture this.

Comment: @JvdV Tks. I will edit that operator. Miss that in my proofing. And you are correct, the regex was designed to return only integers. That was what was shown in his examples. Easily changed if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Try this custom column formula to extract the numbers only:

```
=Number.FromText(
    Text.Combine(
        List.RemoveNulls(
            List.Transform(
                Text.ToList(Text.From([Amount])), 
                each if Value.Is(Value.FromText(_), type number) then _ else null
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Wooley Thanks, good workaround to extract numbers, but in my steps I managed somehow to do the same...the only thing is/was, I wanna divide that extracted number with some value only in a case it finds "brutto" in Amount column.... that is a reason there are strings with "123345 Brutto" - shouldnt be there, any if it does divide with XY...

Answer (score 3):

Its hard to tell what else you are doing in your code, but when you are at the point when you want to extract the number:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"YourPriorStepNameHere", "OnlyAmountNr", each Text.Select([Amount],{"0".."9","."}))
```

you could additionally create table **lookfor** as in image below then use this code to pick up the multiplication factor for Amount column when matching text is found

```
Findmatch = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepNameHere", "Found",  (x) => try Table.SelectRows(lookfor, each  Text.Contains(x[Amount],[Column1], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))[Column2]{0}  otherwise 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I did that actually too...so lets say I wanna divide that extracted number with some value IF it was "brutto" in some value in "Amount" column...

Comment: if its just a few to test, I'd go with a custom column with =if Text.Contains ([Amount],"brutto") then [OnlyAmountNr]/2 else if Text.Contains ([Amount],"CHF") then [OnlyAmountNr]*5 else  [OnlyAmountNr]

Comment: Hmm yeah, it is actually between 2-5 instances on repetetive...but you are right nested IF is always good thing.

Comment: See edited code above for another method to check for contents of cell and assign multiplication factor

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively use scripting, for example Python or R. When you start a new PowerBI project choose to get data from either of the above options.

---

**Python**

[Download](https://www.python.org/) Python and install the [correct pip packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-scripts). I used Pandas to read my dataframe from an Excel file I made using your sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel (r'C:\TestFile.xlsx', dtype=str) # use whatever source to get df
df['OnlyAmountNr'] = df['Amount'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', expand=True).astype(float)
df.loc[df['Amount'].str.contains(r'(?i)\bbrutto\b', regex=True), 'OnlyAmountNr'] = df['OnlyAmountNr']/1.5
df.loc[df['Amount'].str.contains(r'(?i)\bchf\b', regex=True), 'OnlyAmountNr'] = df['OnlyAmountNr']/1.9
```

[image]

- Extract the numbers with potential decimals to a new column using regular expressions. In this case `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`;
- Use 'df.loc' to test another regular expression against all rows in the new column. If it contains `(?i)\bbrutto\b` then devide by 1.5;
- Replicate step above but instead look for `(?i)\bchf\b` and devide by 1.9.

**Note:** Because I read the dataframe from Excel I also had to install the OpenPyxl package. You can install all these pip packages through any Shell, but I used cmd prompt. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907421/9758194) is a link how to do this.

---

**R**

It's also very possible through R. [Download](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/) R for Windows. The only package you'd normally need for this to work is 'stringr'*:

```
library(readxl)
library(stringr)

df <- read_excel("C:\\TestFile.xlsx")
df$OnlyAmountNr <- as.numeric(str_extract(df$Amount,"\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?"))
df$OnlyAmountNr <- ifelse(grepl("(?i)\\bbrutto\\b", df$Amount), df$OnlyAmountNr/1.5, 
                        ifelse(grepl("(?i)\\bchf\\b", df$Amount), df$OnlyAmountNr/1.9, df$OnlyAmountNr))
```

[image]

- Extract the numbers with potential decimals using regular expressions. In this case `(?i)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?`;
- Use 'grepl' for pattern matching with nested 'ifelse' construct to test against `(?i)\\bbrutto\\b` and devide by 1.5 *or* test for `(?i)\\bchf\\b` and devide by 1.9.

***Note:** I used an Excel-file as my df-source again and thus had to download a package called 'readxl' first. This is easy through R itself. Open R > Packages > Install > Choose a CRAN > readxl. The same route can be used to install 'stringr'.

Comment: Damn this is good approach...but I am not skillfull in Python at all :/ you solved it exactly as I wanna have but still....

Comment: @Mirza, I added the `R` alternative too if that helps.

Comment: Thx again! For sure I will test it with both of these programs, but I am unfortunately not a R/Py user...but this seems straightforwards.

Comment: @Mirza, this R answer is the result of one hour google research without much prior knowledge about it. I think it's do-able =) GL