# Flask install/running issues

Tags: python, flask, pip, jinja2, werkzeug

I'm getting very frustrated with trying to get Flask to run. I've tried installing a number of ways, but regardless, I run into some issues without any understanding as to how or why.

Below is an example instance of it messing up. This was my reference: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

### Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$ . venv/bin/activate
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$ pip install Flask
Downloading/unpacking Flask
  Downloading Flask-0.9.tar.gz (481kB): 481kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Flask

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Downloading/unpacking Werkzeug>=0.7 (from Flask)
Downloading Werkzeug-0.8.3.tar.gz (1.1MB): 1.1MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Werkzeug

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Downloading/unpacking Jinja2>=2.4 (from Flask)
Downloading Jinja2-2.7.tar.gz (377kB): 377kB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package Jinja2

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Downloading/unpacking markupsafe (from Jinja2>=2.4->Flask)
Downloading MarkupSafe-0.18.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package markupsafe

Installing collected packages: Flask, Werkzeug, Jinja2, markupsafe
Running setup.py install for Flask

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_themes/.git'
Running setup.py install for Werkzeug

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'werkzeug/debug/templates'
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'examples'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Running setup.py install for Jinja2

warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'custom_fixers'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'jinja2'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory 'docs'
Running setup.py install for markupsafe

building 'markupsafe._speedups' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3    -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c markupsafe/_speedups.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-  2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/markupsafe/_speedups.so
```

Successfully installed Flask Werkzeug Jinja2 markupsafe
Cleaning up...

--

```
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$ touch hello.py
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$ open hello.py
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$ python hello.py
File "hello.py", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file hello.py on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
(venv)Shahs-MacBook-Pro:newpython ssaullah$
```

Shahs-MacBook-Pro:helloflask ssaullah$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 731 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

Answer (score 4):

As the error said - you have a non-ASCII character in your hello.py code but you haven't declared an encoding.  You can fix this by adding a comment to your source code in the first or second line declaring the encoding.  For example, if your file is saved in UTF-8:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

See [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that out - but maybe I should've posted this:

Comment: @user2348946 There is something missing.

Answer (score -1):

try using python's easy_install

```
$python easy_install Flask
```

Comment: See this answer to Why is pip used over easy_install http://stackoverflow.com/a/3220572/158111