# ImportError: No module named requests

Tags: python, python-requests, python-import

I tried importing [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/):

```
import requests
```

But I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named requests

Comment: Did you install `requests`, using `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: I get same issue, I installed via pip

Comment: just to note, I only get the issue from within Spyder, but not the cmd prompt.

Comment: @DavidCrook Did you got the solution? I have the same issue with only my IDE.

Comment: I get  the same result. pip3 reports "Requirement already satisfied:..."

Comment: I solved it; but I can-not recall how I did it.  My guess is that since I was using from Spyder; I was likely in a different environment than I thought I was in and needed to install requests into the environment spyder was using in the IDE.

Comment: For me, it turned out to be a conflict with multiple installations of python.  For instance, on my mac, somehow I've acquired python AND python2.7 in /usr/bin, which do not symlink to the same installation.  Though pip, apparently, is installing modules for python2.7.  Thus, `python` is not seeing those modules.  Using `python2.7`, everything is working.  I suppose I need to clean up my environment a bit.

Comment: requests module needs "charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl". When I installed using pip(pip3) the result is as shown: 


Collecting requests Using cached requests-2.30.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)


Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests) Using cached charset_normalizer-3.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (97 kB) 


It worked well. Please check whether the supported modules exist

Comment: Pyinstaller doesn't see where requests is.... try this 
"pyinstaller app.py --windowed --onefile --hidden-import requests". Use whatever options you need AND --hidden-import <module>

Answer (score 1124):

Requests is not a built in module (does not come with the default python installation), so you will have to install it:

### OSX/Linux

Python 2: `sudo pip install requests`

Python 3: `sudo pip3 install requests`

if you have `pip` installed (`pip` is the package installer for python and should come by default with your python installation).
If pip is installed but not in your path you can use `python -m pip install requests` (or `python3 -m pip install requests` for python3)

Alternatively you can also use `sudo easy_install -U requests` if you have `easy_install` installed.

### Linux

Alternatively you can use your systems package manager:

For centos: `sudo yum install python-requests`

For Debian/Ubuntu Python2: `sudo apt-get install python-requests`

For Debian/Ubuntu Python3: `sudo apt-get install python3-requests`

### Windows

Use `pip install requests` (or `pip3 install requests` for python3) if you have  `pip` installed and Pip.exe added to the Path Environment Variable. If pip is installed but not in your path you can use `python -m pip install requests` (or `python3 -m pip install requests` for python3)

Alternatively from a cmd prompt, use `> Path\easy_install.exe requests`, where `Path` is your `Python*\Scripts` folder, if it was installed. (For example: `C:\Python32\Scripts`)

If you manually want to add a library to a windows machine, you can download the compressed library, uncompress it, and then place it into the `Lib\site-packages` folder of your python path. (For example: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`)

### From Source (Universal)

For any missing library, the source is usually available at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/. You can download requests here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests

On mac osx and windows, after downloading the source zip, uncompress it and from the termiminal/cmd run `python setup.py install` from the uncompressed dir.

([source](https://www.pericror.com/software/importerror-no-module-named-requests))

Comment: If any of you have pip installed on Windows, "pip install requests" will work just fine. I'm guessing that "easy_install requests" will work on osx/linux as well, but pip is generally preferred. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)

Comment: for centos: yum install python-requests

Comment: I got this:`Wheel installs require setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.
pip's wheel support requires setuptools >= 0.8 for dist-info support.`, so frustrating.

Comment: On mac os x, if you have easy_install installed, you can also use: `sudo easy_install -U requests`

Comment: Note for posterity:  for `pip install requests` to work (on a Mac) you need to use `sudo`

Comment: shouldn't it be `> Path\easy_install.py requests`

Comment: On Linux, why do you need sudo for the command to work? It wouldn't work for me until I used sudo but they say you're not supposed to use sudo and pip together. Thanks in advance for the explanation.

Comment: @BourbonCreams depending on the privileges of the user you are currently logged in as, you may not have access to write in the system level directories, which get updated depending on what you install. As a result you use sudo to essentially give yourself root privileges to when executing the command, which ensures you have write access to system directories.

Comment: In Java it is common practice to package dependencies with a project in a `Libraries` folder. Does Python have a similar practice? Or does each developer need to install Requests on their own machine?

Comment: got it working on Mac OS X using: `sudo pip3 install requests`

Comment: Windows: Had to add dir with Pip.exe to Path Environment Variable. Then worked well.

Comment: `sudo apt install python-requests` will work on Kubuntu 18.04.

Comment: i had to restart the terminal after installing requests.

Comment: `apt-get install python3-requests` for python3

Comment: if i have python3 is there any difference between `pip install` and `pip3 install`?

Comment: @MichalH if you have multiple versions of python on your machine (python2.* and python3.*) then you could use pip3 to ensure your installing for python 3. If you just have python3 on your machine, then you can use either.

Comment: For Rocky Linux :  dnf install python-requests

Answer (score 103):

It's not obvious to me which version of Python you are using.

If it's Python 3, a solution would be `sudo pip3 install requests`

Comment: `sudo pip3 install requests` if you want it installed for all users on a machine, not just one user.

Answer (score 79):

To install `requests` module on Debian/Ubuntu for Python2:

`$ sudo apt-get install python-requests`

And for Python3 the command is:

`$ sudo apt-get install python3-requests`

Answer (score 46):

Brew users can use reference below,

command to install `requests`:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

[Homebrew and Python](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-and-Python)

[pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) is the package installer for Python and you need the package `requests`.

Comment: Would you care to add a brief explanation (here) of *why* this works?

Comment: Added extra comment for `pip` info.

Comment: I had to change the python to `~/anaconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/python3 -m pip install requests` `

Answer (score 40):

This may be a liittle bit too late but this command can be run even when pip path is not set. I am using Python 3.7 running on Windows 10 and this is the command

```
py -m pip install requests
```

and you can also replace 'requests' with any other uninstalled library

Answer (score 27):

If you are using Ubuntu, there is need to install `requests`

run this command:

```
pip install requests
```

if you face permission denied error, use sudo before command:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: I am on Mint and am getting the same error even though it is installed.

Answer (score 20):

In my case requests was already installed, but needed an upgrade. The following command did the trick

```
$ sudo pip install requests --upgrade
```

Comment: I tried this and it's still not working. How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 18):

On OSX, the command will depend on the flavour of python installation you have.

Python 2.x - Default

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Python 3.x

```
sudo pip3 install requests
```

Comment: I didn't noticed difference, but it does matter. I have installed **python 3.7** version, and requests using **pip** and it couldn't find it. When I installed via **pip3** it works now.

Comment: Tried 'sudo pip3 install requests' and it seeed to download, but then when running the file with requests in it, got the typical "ImportError: No module named requests".  So frustrating.

Answer (score 14):

On Windows Open **Command Line**

```
pip3 install requests
```

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, so I copied the folder named "requests" from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads[requests download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests#downloads) to 
"/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages". 
Now when you use: import requests, it should work fine.

Comment: Now I've got `No module named urllib3` :)

Comment: @PavelAlexeev try executing this command before "pip install urllib3"

Answer (score 11):

#### In the terminal/command-line:

```
pip install requests
```

then use it inside your Python script by:

```
import requests
```

#### or else if you want to use **pycharm** IDE to install a package:

1. go to setting from File in menu
2. next go to Python interpreter
3. click on `pip`
4. search for `requests` package and install it

Comment: The OP never said anything about pycharm, 99% of users don't use pycharm, and it is totaly unnecessary to use pycharm to install a package, that's a one-line command-line task. Shouldn't even mention pycharm here.

Comment: Yes, 99% of Python users don't use pycharm. Like I said. Ok maybe 'only' 85% don't use it, even if we take JetBrains own numbers. I've personally never seen JetBrains used for Python development inside an org, and only ever heard of it being used in Java-dominated shops. The point again is that the OP never asked for an IDE-specific solution.

Comment: Please prove your point with the document 99%!!! or 85%!!! @smci

Comment: I already told you above what numbers prove that: JetBrains' own numbers(!!!). Even allowing that JetBrains understate the many developers who don't use an IDE, but use vi/emacs.

Comment: lovely answer! for someone who coded in java for 15 years and loves JetBrain tools, pycharm is the first option. This helped me, thx a lot.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using anaconda as your python package manager, execute the following:

```
conda install -c anaconda requests
```

Installing requests through pip didn't help me.

Comment: I needed requests_ntlm, so had to run "conda config --add channels conda-forge" then "conda install -c anaconda requests_ntlm"

Answer (score 7):

Adding Third-party Packages to the Application

Follow this link 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27?hl=en#vendoring

**step1 :** Have a file by named a file named appengine_config.py in the root of your project, then add these lines:

from google.appengine.ext import vendor

## Add any libraries installed in the "lib" folder.

vendor.add('lib')

**Step 2:** create a directory and name it "lib" under root directory of project.

**step 3:** use pip install -t lib requests

**step 4 :** deploy to app engine.

Comment: This was actually what I was looking for. The above steps alone didn't work for AppEngine :)

Answer (score 7):

Try `sudo apt-get install python-requests`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that worked for me:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 7):

## Python [Common installation issues](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#common-installation-issues)

#### **These commands are also useful if [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) screws up your path on macOS.**

```
python -m pip install requests
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

---

#### [Multiple versions of Python installed in parallel?](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

Answer (score 7):

Facing the same issue but unable to fix it with the above solution, so I tried this way and it worked:-

1. curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
2. sudo python2 get-pip.py
3. python -m pip install requests

Comment: Number 3) you can also simply run ```pip install requests```

Comment: please avoid using `sudo` with the pip command if possible

Answer (score 6):

For windows just give path as cd and path to the "Scripts" of python and then execute the command `easy_install.exe` requests.Then try import requests...

Answer (score 6):

In case you hit `pip install requests` and had an output massage of **`Requirement already satisfied`** but yet you still get the error: **`ImportError: No module named requests`**.

*This is likely to happen when you find yourself in a different **interpreter/virtual environment**.*

You can **copy** and **`append`** the **path** of the module into your working environment.
**Note:** *This path usually comes with the message **`Requirement already satisfied`***

Before `import requests`, you should `import sys` and then `append` the **copied path**.

**Example:**
*Command Prompt:*
`pip install requests`
*Output:*
`Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages")
import requests
```

Answer (score 5):

I have had this issue a couple times in the past few months.  I haven't seen a good solution for fedora systems posted, so here's yet another solution.  I'm using RHEL7, and I discovered the following:

If you have `urllib3` installed via `pip`, and `requests` installed via `yum` you will have issues, even if you have the correct packages installed.  The same will apply if you have `urllib3` installed via `yum`, and `requests` installed via `pip`.  Here's what I did to fix the issue:

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
sudo yum remove python-urllib3
sudo yum remove python-requests
```

(confirm that all those libraries have been removed)

```
sudo yum install python-urllib3
sudo yum install python-requests
```

Just be aware that this will only work for systems that are running Fedora, Redhat, or CentOS.

Sources:

 This very question (in the comments to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309309/5220012) answer).

 [This](https://github.com/ejimz/Elasticsearch-zabbix/issues/18) github issue.

Comment: Gave that a try on oracle linux (basically RHEL) but didn't work.  Posting so others can know about this result.  Thanks though~

Comment: @ragerdl Your issue may not specifically be with requests or urllib3.  It could be with other python packages.  It just depends on what you are trying to run.

Comment: Indeed, I had two bad pythons in my path and an alias to a bad python too.  Getting rid of those three python pointers resolved my issue. :)

Answer (score 4):

You must make sure your requests module is not being installed in a more recent version of python.

When using python 3.7, run your python file like:

```
python3 myfile.py
```

or enter python interactive mode with:

```
python3
```

Yes, this works for me. Run your file like this: python3 file.py

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following. If one doesn't work, skip to the next method.

```
pip install requests
```

or...

```
pip3 install requests
```

or...

```
python -m pip install requests
```

or...

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

or...

```
python -m pip3 install requests
```

If all of these don't work, please leave a comment!
How does this work? Depending on the operating system you currently use, the pip command may vary or not work on some. These are the commands you may try in order for a fix.

Answer (score 4):

Type this command in `Command Prompt (Windows)` or `Terminal (Linux/macOS)`:

```
pip install requests
```

Answer (score 3):

I have installed python2.7 and python3.6

Open Command Line to ***~/.bash_profile***  I find that **#Setting PATH for Python 3.6** , So
I change the path to ***PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/bin:${PATH}"*** , 
(please make sure your python2.7's path) ,then save.
It works for me.

Answer (score 3):

if you want `request` import on windows:

```
pip install request
```

then `beautifulsoup4` for:

```
pip3 install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: I think what you mean is "requests" not "request". There is no library named "request"

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.You can try this method.
In this file '.bash_profile', Add codes like `alias python=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7`

Answer (score 2):

I found that my issue was VSCode was reading from the wrong Python Interpreter. [This youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ud9Y2uB4PY) solved it for me.

Comment: Please do not link to youtube tutorials. They are stale and will go out of date, and are not necessarily available to everyone

Answer (score 1):

My answer is basically the same as @pi-k. In my case my program worked locally but failed to build on QA servers. (I suspect devops had older versions of the package blocked and my version must have been too out-of-date) I just decided to upgrade everything

```
$ pip install pip-review
$ pip-review --local --interactive
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an import error because requests are not a built-in module instead, it is created by someone else and you need to install the requests.

use the following command on your terminal then it will work correctly.

```
pip install requests
```

[Install python requests library](https://www.alixaprodev.com/2021/12/how-to-install-requests-library-in-python.html) and this error will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using anaconda
**step 1**:
 where python
**step 2**:
 open anaconda prompt in administrator mode
**step 3**:
 cd <*python path*>
**step 4**:
 install the package in this location

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was showing request Requirement already satisfied .
so  I use.

```
sudo pip3 install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error even though I installed 'requests' several times. The problem was that I was installing requests in the global Python environment and not in the app virtual environment. Once I installed requests in the Virtual environment, the error disappeared. So here is a good reading on how to install 'requests' in the app virtual environment: [Virtual Environments and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following [this tutorial](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project):

```
$ pipenv install requests
Installing requests...
Adding requests to Pipfile's [packages]...
 Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
 Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (a290a1)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a290a1)...
   ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
$ pipenv shell
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
 . /home/[user]/.local/share/virtualenvs/[id]/bin/activate
$ python3
Python 3.10.5 (main, Jul  5 2022, 00:20:23) [GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/ip')
>>> print('Your IP is {0}'.format(response.json()['origin']))
Your IP is xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

What did actually work for me, and is going to work for you is to find out the path of yours scripts folder

1. For example C:\Python31\Scripts
2. Via CMD, navigate with CD to this folder
3. Type > pip, to see wether is there/it does work
4. pip install requests; or any other packages that produces the error.
5. Done

[image: Operation done]

Best Regards,
Roman

Comment: thank you for your efforts to provide an answer. How is you answer any different from the existing ones ? at the end you just install requests as suggested in the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller doesn't see where requests is.... try this:

`pyinstaller app.py --windowed --onefile --hidden-import requests`

Use whatever options you need AND --hidden-import *module*. This is tested and works when there is a local import package that uses requests but requests is not imported directly into the py file you are compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to resolve this issue. I tried this in
Windows - VS Code. The issue got resolved.

1. Create a virtual environment `py -m venv venv`
2. Activate the virtual environment `.\venv\Scripts\activate`
3. Install the library `pip install requests`
4. Run your python program `py abc.py`