# No module named for 'requests'

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have two Ubuntu servers. Entering the below on server **Server A** works fine:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
```

**Server B however**,

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
>>> from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.poolmanager
```

Both have the same version:

```
Name: requests
Version: 2.7.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires:
```

What’s going on here?

Here is Server B's paths:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/greenlet-0.4.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent-1.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Server B has the file located here, so it should find it:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3
```

Comment: [Did you install `requests`, using `pip` or `easy_install`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests#comment25103544_17309288)

Comment: @BhargavRao installed using pip.

Comment: Be sure you dont have a script  named `requests.py` on that folder in server B

Comment: In the same folder of server B, execute `>>> import requests
>>> requests.__path__` and tell us what you have as output

Comment: @bigOTHER gives ``['/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests']`` should it not be ``/usr/local/lib/python2.7/``

Comment: Looks like the sys.path is in the wrong order. can this be changed?

Comment: Its ok with `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. you can change the order, it's a `list`, so you can manipulate it

Comment: Would this be permanent?

Comment: @Falcon1 not permanent;  why not just use urllib3 directly like: `from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager`

Comment: Thats what I'm trying to do ``from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager`` but it looks like it finding an other version in ``/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests`` which does not ship with urllib3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an issue in `python-requests` as the owners did not package it the same between PyPI and Ubuntu repository as mentioned [here](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive/issues/13).

**Solutions:**

1. Use `urllib3` directly:

   ```
    from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
   ```
2. Remove completely all copies of `python-requests` than re-install it either using `pip` or using `apt-get`, the one that includes `packages.urllib3` inside.

Comment: Option 2 how can I remove the version from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests? pip uninstall removes it from the wrong one.

Comment: If it was installed via apt-get, try : `sudo apt-get remove python-requests` , else just remove the folder.