# Linking views to webpage with Django and a2 servers

Tags: python, django, .htaccess

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this issue I'm having as it seems like a simple one but I've been banging my head on this for the past couple hours with no solace. OK, so I set up Django following the A2 Hosting guide [here](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-with-fastcgi-on-shared-hosting).

And I'm just not able to communicate with my **views.py** file.

Let me show you some files as I'm hoping its just some blatant error.

**public_html/mysite/mysite/setup.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'nfl'
)

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': '*******',
    'USER': '*******',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': '5432',
}
}
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "nfl/templates",

)
```

**public_html/mysite/mysite/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^home/', 'nfl.views.home', name='home'),

]
```

**public_html/mysite/nfl/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import nfldb
import requests
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    db = nfldb.connect()
    q = nfldb.Query(db)
    year = request.GET['year']
    if year is none:
            year = 2014


    q.game(season_year=year, season_type='Regular')
    qb = []
    for pp in q.sort('passing_yds').limit(10).as_aggregate():
            qb.append(pp)
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'qb' : qb})
```

**public_html/mysite/nfl/templates/index.html:**

```
just a helloworld html file to test
```

**.htaccess:**

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on
# Set up static content redirect:
RewriteRule static/(.+)$ mysite/public/static/$1
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

And when I go to my domain, I just get the basic *congrats on your first Django app page*.

So what am I missing here? I copied most over from my local machine because it was working there on the local host with the Django `runserver` but now I can't seem to link my **views**.

Let me know if there's any other info needed or if there's a better website to go to.

**My setup:**

- Python: 2.7
- Django: 1.85

Comment: @@panthor314 By "when I go to my domain" do you mean domain.com? Because in your URLs.py, in order to access your "home" view, you have to go to "^home/" i.e. domain.com/home

Comment: wow that seemed to work(THANKS!!!)... now its saying no module named requests eventhough its installed...

Comment: Is it pointing to the "import requests" line in your views.py when it raises the "no module named requests" error? If yes, it seems like requests is not a built-in module. See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests Did you install it using "pip install requests" on your production (current) server? If no, how exactly did you install it?

Comment: @user2719875 yeah yeah its pointing to my views.py, but yes i pip installed it on my server, dont know why it wont recognize

Comment: can you give me the output of the "pip freeze" command?

Comment: @user2719875 OK so i changed to djangoenv and then installed requests there and that worked now its looking for the config.ini file of my db so hopefully im on the right track!

Comment: @user2719875 pip freeze:Django==1.8.5
Paste==2.0.2
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
enum34==1.0.4
flup==1.0.3.dev20110405
httplib2==0.9.2
nfldb==0.2.11
nflgame==1.2.17
psycopg2==2.6.1
pytz==2015.6
requests==2.8.1
six==1.10.0
wsgiref==0.1.2

Comment: Okay sounds good. I'm going to post my first comment as the answer to this question (because that is the answer to the original question). If you have any other issues, just ask in a new post. This avoids the "ask question x but end up solving question y and z" issue. You can check the answer off if it correctly answers the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to domain.com, then the "Congrats on your first django app" page will appear, because in your URLs.py, you do specify a view for

```
url(r'^')
```

In order to not show this page, and to show your index.html page instead, you should do

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', 'nfl.views.home', name='home'),
]
```