# Can not solve ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests).

1. I installed pip and I executed

   ```
   pip install requests
   ```

   and got

   ```
   Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg
   Cleaning up...
   ```
2. I started my Python 2 shell:

   ```
   >>> from urllib.request import urlopen
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ImportError: No module named request
   ```

Why am I still catching this exception? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Related: '`request`' vs '`requests`' (the latter with '`s`'): [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&amp;lq=1#comment134785674_76440240) e.g. *[Several malicious typosquatted Python libraries found on PyPI repository](https://thehackernews.com/2021/07/several-malicious-typosquatted-python.html)*. That is, 'requests' (the real library) vs. 'request' (the malicious one). It is no wonder the [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) attack was successful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confusing the 3rd party module named `requests` with the Python 3's built-in `urllib.request`. You can use

```
import requests
```

both with Python 2 and 3. However, you can use

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

only with Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

- [`urllib.requests` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) is available in Python 3.x. In Python 2.x, it's [`urllib` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html)
- You installed the third-party library `requests`, but you are trying to import a standard module.

Just you import `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to install `python-pip` with this command:

`sudo apt install python-pip`

then I update it with this command

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score -1):

You have installed request(s) and you want to import a module from request. It's not the same.

The module *request* exists only on Python 3. Python 2 doesn't have this module.

If you want to use *urlopen*, you don't need to install *requests*. You must only use Python 3.

Comment: Re *"The module request exists only on Python 3"*: What?

Comment: '`request`' vs '`requests`' (the latter with '`s`'): [See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76440240/getting-this-error-while-installing-the-request-module-of-python?noredirect=1&amp;lq=1#comment134785674_76440240) e.g. *[Several malicious typosquatted Python libraries found on PyPI repository](https://thehackernews.com/2021/07/several-malicious-typosquatted-python.html)*. That is, 'requests' (the real library) vs. 'request' (the malicious one). It is no wonder the [typosquatting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) attack was successful.