# LevPasha/instabot.py » Wont to work when i start script in Terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

LevPasha/instabot.py » Won't to work when i start script in Terminal

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 6, in <module>
from instabot import InstaBot
File "/Library/insta/src/instabot.py", line 4, in <module>
from userinfo import UserInfo
File "/Library/insta/src/userinfo.py", line 4, in <module>
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Thats what i see in my terminal. What to do?
I changed username and password in example.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Comment: `pip install requests`

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: But i installed pip ?

Comment: How? Using pip on command line?

Comment: i'm using windows

Comment: I dont know how much you know so I will explain at the most basic level. Holding the window key press R and then let go. A run box will appear. Type 'cmd' and then a console window should appear. In this window type pip install requests

Comment: i saw this message pip command not exists

Comment: Ok, type instead python -m pip install -U pip

Comment: Also what version of python are you using? Python should ship with PIP

Comment: i'm using python 3 but i didn't install it correctly please help me to install it :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the respective console of the OS.

**Windows: (cmd)**

```
pip install requests
```

**Ubuntu and Debian (terminal)**

```
sudo apt-get install python-requests
```

This will install requests module

Comment: ok but i have a problem with the installation of python 3, the command python can't run on the terminal

Comment: Late comment. Reinstall python and check option install to path.