# Import of nltk version 3.2.3 fails with ImportError

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, nltk

I'm running python 2.7.13 under windows 10 and I'm struggling to get nltk properly running.
Here's what happens when I try to import nltk:

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in <module>
 import nltk
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
 from nltk.chunk import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
 from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 13, in <module>
 from nltk.parse import ParserI
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\parse\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
 from nltk.parse.corenlp import CoreNLPParser, CoreNLPDependencyParser
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk-3.2.3-py2.7-win32.egg\nltk\parse\corenlp.py", line 17, in <module>
 import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

The following packages are installed:

- cycler 0.10.0
- functools32 3.2.3.post2
- matplotlib 2.0.2
- nltk 3.2.3
- numpy 1.12.1
- pyparsing 2.2.0
- python-dateutil 2.6.0
- pytz 2017.2
- PyYAML 3.12
- six 1.10.0

I have already tried to uninstall nltk and also uninstalled and reinstalled python and then I followed these instructions:
http://lizusefulstuff.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-install-nltk-package-for-python.html

However, with these instructions I get stuck with step 5. When I enter

```
python -m nltk.downloader
```

I get the message

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: No module named requests
```

Does anyone have a hint what I'm doing wrong here or what else I could try to get nltk running in my setup? I assume there is still a way to use nltk with python 2.7?

From what I found so far, it seems easier to install nltk with python 3.4 but I'd like to avoid a python upgrade, if possible, since aside from my nltk experiments I'm following along a coding tutorial that refers to python 2.7.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: install `requests` perhaps?

Comment: try `pip install requests` to install requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Comment: Installing `requests` solved it, now I can import nltk without error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of `nltk` (v3.2.3), there's an issue with "optional" dependency, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1725

**The `ImportError` would happen in any OS (Windows / Linux / Mac) since it's a python dependency issue.**

This is due to the additional dependency that `nltk.parse.corenlp` needs but it isn't elegantly imported and the imports were exposed at the top level at [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/**init**.py#L81](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/parse/__init__.py#L81)

To install `nltk` with `requests` to patch this problem:

```
pip install -U nltk[corenlp]
```

For fuzz-free installation, installs all packages that all `nltk` submodules would require:

```
pip install -U nltk[all]
```

Alternatively, you can install the request package separatedly:

```
pip install requests
```

Hopefully, issue #1725 gets resolved soon and a minor patched version of the release will be re-released soon.