# ModuleNotFoundError with a python requests library

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is anyone else receiving a moduleNotFoundError with their requests library? Not sure why this is happening. The library is installed as well which is even more confusing.

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

and the resulting error was this:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [1], line 4
      2 import csv
      3 from datetime import datetime
----> 4 import requests
      5 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

when i run `pip freeze` I can confirm I have requests installed as well, see below:

[Screenshot from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eENSn.png)

I have requests version `requests==2.28.1`

Comment: Probably you have not installed requests module yet. Install it using this command in your terminal: pip install requests

Comment: Please do some research before asking.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you don't have the requests module installed. Run the following command:
`pip install requests` to install the package.

Comment: Sorry, i completely forgot to mention that I have the library installed.

Answer (score 0):

corrected the error by referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859673/modulenotfounderror-requests-despite-installation-attemps-showing-requirement) (i didnt see it when I first searched)

running `sudo pip3 install requests` and it recognized the library now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).