# pip install requests fails because it's already installed but I also get "ImportError: no module requests"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I'm setting up my MacBook Pro and hitting some snags related to Python versions and pip.

I try to run:

```
$ ./myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./better_publishing.py", line 7, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

But when I try to `pip install`:

```
$ pip install requests
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.25.3)
```

pip version:

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.5
```

Would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: By any chance do you have multiple versions of Python installed?

Comment: Yeah I do. In my `.zshrc` I also have `alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: Do you have pip3 in your machine.?

Comment: if so try pip3 install requests

Comment: this issue has already an answer here:
[importerror-no-module-named-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Comment: I get the same "requirement already satisfied" message from `pip3 install requests`

Comment: Personally I would advise against aliasing `python` to `python3` on Mac, although I'm not sure there's anything inherently wrong with doing so. I'd use something like [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your python installs. I suspect what you have is that your `pip`/`pip3` are not associated with the version of `python3` that is being used maybe. Have you tried pip installing some other package and importing that, to check if this is really a `requests` only issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would try uninstalling the module and re-installing it.
Here are the commands:

```sh
$ pip uninstall requests
$ pip install requests
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking if requests is listed with `pip list`?

If yes then you can try `pip uninstall requests`. If this also gets you an error, than you can try to delete the package in the finder.

After this I was able to use `pip install <some_package>` again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add this on the first line of `myscript.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```