# WebScraping with Python: Request import error

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting started to the web scraping "world". 
This is my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

theurl = "https://twitter.com/realdonaldtrump";
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(theurl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")

print (soup.title)
```

When I try to run the code I have the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ACC/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/imp.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've already went to the project interpreter on settings and installed requests, and I've already did pip install requests on terminal.

Comment: I believe this could be an issue with PyCharm (I have had similar issues before) maybe this will help you as it did me https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000410510-PyCharm-won-t-recognize-installed-module

Comment: Use ```requests``` instead of ```urllib```

Comment: or add this and use it: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/urllib/request.py

Comment: Also good to check which python interpreter pycharm is using, in case you have selected a different variant than the one used on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3 try using "requests" instead

```
pip3 install requests
```

Here is how I solve it [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)