# Error message in IDLE 3.8.2: No module named 'discord'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run an idle file in python 3.8.2... An error keeps popping up and says "No module named 'discord'". I'm trying to make a discord bot, but IDLE can't seem to find a module called discord. It keeps highlighting the `import discord` statement on line 1.

Comment: Did you install discord through pip?

Comment: I just did and it worked thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't installed discord module. Please install it using "pip install discord"