# Not able to import a module that is already installed

Tags: python, module, pip, python-3.6, site-packages

I am trying to import a module "**requests**" but it shows the following error

> File "manager.py", line 12,
>
> import requests
>
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'**

Then I also verified the pip list using

```
python -m pip list
```

and it includes the requests module. also when I try to import it in the python interpreter it successfully imports the module.

```
>>> import requests
```

when I try

```
pip install requests
```

its says ***Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages***

How can I resolve his issue ???

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: What is the output of ``python --version``?

Comment: Check if this thread helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309309/8612226

Comment: @MisterMiyagi python --version: Python 2.7.5 while python3 --version: Python 3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)

Comment: @JonathanMachado thanks but that's not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) variables are correct. I've messed up before where the "site-packages" path got removed and caused imports to get wonky.

Comment: Thanks, actually am running on remote server. Can you tell me how can i update the sys.path file. Other imports are working just requests is not working.

Comment: You can use the `sys.path.append()` or `sys.path.insert()` functions, however, if other non-built-in packages are importing than this is likely not the issue.

Comment: I also should have said that you can use `sys.path.remove()` if there is an errant entry that you want to change with `insert`.