# Huge problem of installing pip-requests (no help found in all SO yet)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-requests, pycharm

I was based on this question (I've read a lot more, but this one I took as example):
[ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

I've made all the possible activities in command line:

1. `pip install requests` (when I try `pip3 install requests` - I recieve only `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_0exyfp'`about 15-20 files before)
2. `pip install requests --user`
3. `pip -m install requests --user`
4. `python -m pip install requests --user`
5. `cd C:\Program Files\Python38` (directory of python) and made first 4 steps.
6. `cd C:\Users\Фёдор\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38` (directory of it's appdata) and made first 4 steps.
7. Downloaded https://pypi.org/project/requests/ and trying to launch setup 
   (I didn't made and didn't read how to install because there are no instruction there)
8. After the downloading zip - I've unzipped it into `C:\Users\Фёдор` (my user - deafult launch of command line), 
   I've unzipped into directory from point 4 and appdata from point 5.
9. I was trying to launch `python setup.py install` and added `--user` every time as well in all 3 directories (my user, directory of python, directory of appdata), with all the possible errors on my way: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\program files\\python38\\Lib\\site-packages\\accesstest_deleteme_fishfingers_custard_0exyfp'`, as well as `ImportError: No module named requests`.

The last result seems right, right? (I have it in all 3 directories that I've described before - all seems successful). Note appears, that I've already installed everything and so on:
[image]

However, the result in PyCharm (I write Python code).

[image]

Comment: try pip3 install requests

Comment: Have you tried using PyCharm's functionality to install requests in the interpreter you're actually using?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe  how can I possibly use PyCharm functionally to install requests right inside the interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved a problem and I DIDN'T SEE ANY SIMILAR INFORMATION IN THE WHOLE SO YET:

1. Old project need to be redone completely. For some reason, new installations doesn't implement well to old existed projects.
2. For better and absolutely truthful installation on PyCharm, User should go to Settings - `"Project: #name of current project#"` - `Python interpreter`, then click on `+` at the right side of opened window, then write "requests" inside a search bar, and after that - "install package" at the bottom of window.

Only after these two steps PyCharm finally sees and can work with requests.