# path python multiple versions

Tags: python, path

i'm new to programming and i think i already screw up a few things. and i'm sorry because this thing will be probably like your grandfather asking help for his facebook so please forgive me lol.

i have almost no idea what PATH is but i guess i broke it because when i pip install a package or something like that my code doesn't work. people said it's because i have two version of python 3.7 and 3.8

so when i write to terminal this: open ~/.bash_profile

it shows this:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

and when i type this: echo $PATH

it shows this:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

so the thing is i already delete 3.8 (or i thought i did) with these things

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
sudo rm -rf '/Applications/Python 3.8'
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/python3
```

yet still i have problems with executing my code.

i use mac.

Comment: With which command you execute your code and what kind of error it displayed?

Comment: hi i wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61961058/cant-fix-importerror-no-module-named-request-error

Comment: Can you try to replace `import urllib.request` with `import urllib` and `import urllib3`?