# ModuleNotFoundError for requests

Tags: python, pip, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I'm extremely new to Python, so I can only apologize for my unadulterated incompetence.

I'm trying to learn to web scrape, so I did `pip install requests` and that worked fine.

In PyCharm, however, I receive `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'` when I try `import requests`.

PyCharm offers `from pip._vendor import requests` to rectify this, but from this I get:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pip._vendor.requests' has no attribute 'Session' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try this question, maybe there is already an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm may be using a different python (perhaps from a virtualenv) than the one you pip installed from.

You should also be able to `pip install requests` from PyCharm's terminal, which *should* be using the same python as the code you ran.

If you're not using a virtual environment, or similar, I'd *highly* recommend it. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html# might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `python -m pip install requests` or this `python3 -m pip install requests`