# Can't get Python 3.8.3 to recognize bitcoin module

Tags: python, pip, bitcoin

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nhkjdk/Documents/Tutorial.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bitcoin import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoin'
>>>
```

I have Python 3.8.3 -- I've installed pip install cryptos from https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools.git

Cannot import from cryptos ...

Keep getting this error:

```
>>> from cryptos import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from cryptos import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptos/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .coins import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptos/coins/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .bitcoin import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptos/coins/bitcoin.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..explorers import blockchain
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptos/explorers/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import base_insight, bitpay, blockdozer, dash_siampm, sochain
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptos/explorers/base_insight.py", line 2, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Anyone have any idea???
Thanks.

Comment: What about `pip install requests`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in the terminal.
This will install the missing package "Requests".

```
python3 -m pip install requests --user
```