# "ModuleNotFoundError: No Module Named 'requests'" with Visual Studio Code on macOS

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, python-requests

I am having a problem running my script in Visual Studio Code.

I have tried the following:

1. Reinstalling requests through `pip`, `easy_install`, and `sudo pip`
2. Importing `requests` directly in the Python interpreter (which worked)

This leads me to believe that Visual Studio Code isn't using the correct interpreter that actually has the package installed.

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment? I remember having this issue with `requests` (not on MacOS nor with VSCode, but on Windows with plain-old IDLE); while I don't know what causes this behavior, I was able to solve it by creating a virtual environment and configuring my IDE (switched to PyCharm) to use that virtual environment interpreter.

Comment: I am not using a vm. Running on a 2019 MacBook Pro with the latest version of Big Sur. Thanks for the advice in case I use a VM in the furture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can choose your interpreter in VS Code in several ways. One of them is by clicking the tab in the bottom toolbar (lower-left) which might say "Python 3.9.4 (64-bit)", upon which you will be able to select from a menu of choices, e.g. /usr/bin/python3 or a conda or brew installation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think yours is a Python environment problem. To check whether it's Python environment or not, you can use `which python` (or `which python3` if you use Python 3) command in your both Visual Studio Code terminal and Mac terminal. If you see different python path, then your Visual Studio Code is using different python environment. You can [change](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=To%20do%20so%2C%20open%20the,Settings%2C%20with%20the%20appropriate%20interpreter.) the Python interpreter in Visual Studio Code to have same environment as your Mac terminal.

- Open Command Palette in Visual Studio Code with <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
- Type **"Python: Select Interpreter"**

Then, choose the same environment as your Mac terminal (if you want the same one, you can choose the same Python environment path as Mac terminal that you get with **"which python"** or **"which python3"**).

Comment: Sadly they are both showing the same location as /usr/bin/python

Comment: I think you used python3. I forgot to add that in mine. Btw, glad you already solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to find a solution here: [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

You haven't mentioned using different versions in your commands. It's possible you need to use `pip3` instead of `pip`, or `python3` instead of `python`.