# Why do I get an ImportError when I try to import the beautifulsoup module? Can somebody help, please?

Tags: python, anaconda

When I use the code "from bs4 import beautifulsoup as bs" I get the following ImportError: ImportError with a directory: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup4' from 'bs4' (C:\Users.........anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4_*init*_.py)

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem? Your question lacks focus. There are tons of similar types already available. Flagging the question to be closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Answer (score 0):

Have you already installed beautifulsoup4 module??
if not please firstly install the module..

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Yes, I did install it and restart my computer.

Comment: @AnsumanaKorleh ok try to  import correctly now ```from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs```

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure that module is already installed.

```
>>> import bs4
```

If the module is not installed, you will seethis error `ModuleNotFoundError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
>>>
```

- Install the module with pip

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

- Import the module correctly..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```