# No module named 'unidecode'

Tags: python

```
from unidecode import unidecode
```

Although I installed unidecode with

```
pip install unidecode
```

there is still an error like in the title. I am working on a PyCharm and i Installed it on a terminal being in folder: Scripts.

Comment: Are you sure PyCharm is using the exact same Python interpreter that was used to install the module?

Comment: Did this answer your question? [No module found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Comment: Try doing `pip install unidecode` in the terminal in PyCharm. I ran into a similar problem a couple months ago and this seemed to work for me.

Comment: @Hhadley I thought about it and still the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that your Pythons are coming from the same place? While I was having this issue, my terminal was accessing python from a different place on my computer than my pycharm was. I had to create a new enviornment and set the path to what my terminal was.

Answer (score 3):

In Pycharm try to go to "Python Packages" section placed in the bottom, search it and install.

In addition, a mirror of the package [here](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode)

Or run in this way:

```
pip install Unidecode
```