# PyDictionary import issue

Tags: python, django, module, pydictionary

I am having issues on Mac OS installing PyDictionary into a Django project. When I `pip3 install PyDictionary` it says `Requirement already satisfied:`
when I enter the command `pip3 freeze` it shows me
`PyDictionary==2.0.1` is already installed.

But it can't find the module for some reason:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def word(request):
    search = request.GET.get('search')
    dictionary = PyDictionary()
    meaning = dictionary.meaning(search)
    synonyms = dictionary.synonym(search)
    antonyms = dictionary.antonym(search)
    context = {
        'meaning': meaning,
        'synonyms': synonyms,
        'antonyms': antonyms
    }
    return render(request, 'word.html')
```

I get the error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/natelampros/PycharmProjects/english_dictionary/englishdictionary/dictionary/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/natelampros/PycharmProjects/english_dictionary/englishdictionary/dictionary/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDictionary'
```

I've looked and can not find out why it can't find the module. I've tried installing PyDictionary on vs code and in terminal and it says it's installed every time.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [requirement already satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip3` installs module for one Python but you run code with other Python. Try `python3.10 -m pip install ...`, or `pip3.10 install ...`