# pyhton vscode venv ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup, virtual-environment

I'm in my virtual environment in vscode, installed `beautifulsoup`, and I can see the latest version file in the virtual environment files, and I'm running the notebook yet it gives the error of `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'`, any help here?

NB: when I write `pip show beautifulsoup4`, it gives me all the details about the package version 4.11.1

I pip install beautifulsoup4 and pip install bs4

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [ModuleNotFoundError:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Comment: What precisely did you do? You only paraphrase your actions, which only allows guessing. Also, reduce the scope of your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Make sure the interpreter version you are using is the same environment where you installed the `bs4` package.

- Click on the python version at the top right of the jupyter notebook

  [image]
- Select the interpreter environment where the `bs4` package is installed

  [image]