# Installation error streamlit: Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error

Tags: python, runtime-error, streamlit

I try to install metaploit, but every time I get errors and I can't get it to work.

During installation I get the following error code:

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit

(Deleted a lot of irrelevant information)


Building wheels for collected packages: pyarrow
  Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyarrow (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [291 lines of output]


  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      error: command 'D:\\Eind Project Programming Final\\venv\\Scripts\\cmake.exe' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyarrow
Failed to build pyarrow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyarrow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

**I have already tried the following:**

- Re-install Pycharm and Python and install the 64 bit version. (Running no other python or program)
- Tried different versions of the packages.
- Deleted & Re-installed packages.
- Finding a solution on google.
- (Latest python, pycharm version and all the packages I updated to the lastest versions.)

**Tried these commands:**

```
pip uninstall streamlit
pip uninstall wheel 
pip uninstall setuptools
pip uninstall pip
pip install --upgrade streamlit
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade wheel
pip install --upgrade pyarrow
pip install --upgrade cmake
```

Comment: pyproject.toml is used in poetry if I am not wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named ....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Answer (score 12):

Are you using Python 3.11? Because in that case, it's described in [this issue](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5608): `pyarrow` doesn't support Python 3.11 yet (here is [the PR in `pyarrow`'s github](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/14499), it'll arrive in the next release). So either you simply wait until that is released, or you install Python 3.10 until then.

Answer (score 6):

As of today, there is not pyarrow for Python 3.11 on wheel with precompiled binaries. That means you have two options:

1. Build it yourself which is quite a ride [[`pyarrow` documentation]](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#building-on-linux-and-macos)
2. Use `pip` with the nightly build [[`pyarrow` documentation]](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/developers/python.html#installing-nightly-packages) which is reasonable:

```
pip install --extra-index-url https://pypi.fury.io/arrow-nightlies/ \
        --prefer-binary --pre pyarrow
```

Answer (score 3):

The main error here you are getting is,

```
No module named 'cmake'
```

While you have gotten to the depths of the problem and tried a few other solutions I wonder what this one returned as a result.

```
pip install --upgrade cmake
```

I tried to download cmake into a new virtualenvironment and it worked just fine. I would also suggest that you start a new environment start by building cmake and go along with whatever you are gonna install next.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Unfortunately I still have the problem after these steps. (I installed beforehand to poetry )

Comment: Have you tried updating your pip? From my experience the wheel problems occur because of unupdated pip issues.

Answer (score 1):

As of January 2024, this works. You can build wheels for the pyarrow with the line below:

```
pip install pyarrow==14.0.0
```