# matplotlib/PIL mismatched versions

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I just cannot find any solution for this

no matter if I run the code in Jupyter or from the command line

even after installing Pillow

```
>pip install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\phil\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)

>pip3 install Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in c:\users\phil\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (9.0.1)
```

matplotlib keeps trying to use an obsolete plugin

```
>python test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\test3.py", line 2, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 113, in <module>
    from . import _api, _version, cbook, _docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 27, in <module>
    from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, is_color_like
  File "C:\Users\phil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py", line 51, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

workaround I had to edit matplotlibfiles to replace PIL by pi to make it work

- is there no other way around this ?
- is matplotlib deprecated ?

any help appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Comment: no, that's why I posted this. since I used pip I'd expect matplotlib and Pillow would be compatible

Comment: Try this in command line, `python` and the `import PIL` then post the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The package is installed in a different venv while you are in another. You can append the package directory into your working environment before you import.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("c:/users/phil/appdata/local/programs/python/python39/lib/site-packages")
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: well no, this is precisely what is imported and I had to replace all 'PIL' by 'pil' in >40 files

Comment: Your python libs are getting installed at different place, you will definitely that where exactly it is getting installed.

Comment: I used pip and pip3. replying package is already installed. I was expecting the packages to be installed and used there. I'll keep digging but it makes no sense so far