# Spectral Python - No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, numpy, spectral-python

So I am following along with the `Spectral` python documentation and I have all the required packages and other python dependicies installed yet I keep getting an error that shows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\asus\OneDrive\Research\My Code\spectrial.py", line 1, in <module>
    import spectral.io.erdas as erdas
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\spectral\__init__.py", line 21, in 
<module>
    from .utilities.errors import SpyException
  File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages\spectral\utilities\errors.py", 
  line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Here is my Code:

```
import spectral.io.erdas as erdas
import numpy as np
from spectral import *

img = open_image('photo.lan')

img.__class__
spectral.io.bilfile.BilFile
print(img)
```

When I run `pip show numpy` I get this:

```
Name: numpy
Version: 1.21.3
```

Is there anything I could be missing for this to keep happening?

Comment: Did your try this? [No module named ....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73398463/19290081)

Comment: What is your python version? And on what system are you trying run the code (Mac with M1)?

Comment: pip3.9 show numpy ?

Comment: pythin 3.9 and everything says I have numpy 1.21.3