# PIP install path

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I'm trying to run a custom script from notion API to rainmeter and to do this I have a py file and for some reason, I don't have requests installed.

When installed requests it said "No Module Found" and when I found out the issue is I have to change the path folder I searched over the stack and everywhere else but I couldn't find it. The question I have is how to do anything I'm a noobie and I want to get requests onto the file I'm working on.

Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Did you execute pip install requests?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)