# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src' - Python

Tags: python, keras, model, pickle, streamlit

I am trying to load my model with this code:

```
`# Load the model 
with open('tomato_model.pkl', 'rb') as model_file:
    #from keras.models import load_model
    model = pickle.load(model_file)`
```

But it kept on returning this errror:

#`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.src' Traceback: File "C:\Users\CleanTech\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 534, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\Users\CleanTech\Desktop\Tomatoe\tomato.py", line 156, in <module> model = pickle.load(model_file)`
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

And there's no where in my code or model with such module named 'keras.src'

Alternatively I tried using:

`with open('tomato_model.pkl', 'rb') as model_file: from keras.models import load_model model = load(model_file)`

Still my `streamlit` could not load rather throwing error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests)

Answer (score 1):

Although you aren't using `keras` anywhere, Streamlit still requires it to work properly. And you are most probably not using the correct version of keras

To install the updated version of `keras` run the command:

```bash
pip install keras==2.12
```

Comment: I have that installed already, when I tried installing pip install keras, it returns requirement already met

Comment: @SADIQ Then it is most likely that it is a version issue. try `pip install keras==2.12`

Comment: Thank you @Umar I have also tried this and it was still the same

Comment: @SADIQ Then does this answer your question: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/keras-module-not-found/6866/2 ?