python-oracledb on AWS Lambda Windows issue
I have a task to connect to an AWS RDS Oracle server and retrieve information using lambda layer. I have been working on this issue for almost two days. I discovered a lightweight Oracle database installation called python-oracledb but haven't been able to resolve the problem. I need help.
I am using Windows on my local machine, and the Oracle RDS is on a Windows EC2 instance as well.
Here is the error I am encountering:
`
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'oracledb'
Traceback (most recent call last)
RequestId: 87f11785-14c0-4a8c-8dbf-61be98995b82
REPORT RequestId: 87f11785-14c0-4a8c-8dbf-61be98995b82 Duration: 3.22 ms Billed Duration: 4 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 61 MB Init Duration: 255.42 ms
`

I have referred to both ChatGPT, stackoverflow and Oracle documentation on using oracle-db, but I keep encountering the same error. I also attempted to use cx_oracle with the Oracle client, but I faced errors and size limitations when uploading it as a Lambda layer.
Steps I have taken:
Created a directory for the lambda layer:
`mkdir lambda_layer
cd lambda_layer
mkdir python`

Installed the oracledb package:
`pip install oracledb -t ./python`

Created a zip file for the layer:
cd python
zip -r ../python_oracledb_layer.zip .

I uploaded the python_oracledb_layer.zip file and ensured I used Python 3.12, which was used for local compilation (I've also tried other runtime versions). However, I still encounter the same error.

oracledb folder


Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests (different module but the same principle still applies - you need to install the module, using pip install, so python can use it).

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with details of: the contents of the layer zip file including the install.sh script and/or how you create the python site_packages directory within the zip file.

@MT0 I do not understand what you mean how I created the site_packages, but I do note that the site_packages are in appdata\lib...... which might already be preinstalled. I have included the screenshot and where is the install.sh
Is there any step am missing?

The documentation for layers is here and this part of the documentation discusses site_packages (which you would use if you were including the python module in the zip file rather than pip installing it). There are sample layers here and here.

thank you and let me go through this and will let you know by end of today. thanks alot

I have this error now after starting again using the documentation.
Response
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'base_impl' from partially initialized module 'oracledb' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/init.py)",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "0beb35cc-16a9-451a-b13c-b21e5d58a12d",
"stackTrace": []
}
I have to include this sys.path.append('/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages')  in the lambda to get this

I have also download docker and use amazon linux and the same error  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'base_impl' from partially initialized module 'oracledb' (most likely due to a circular import) (/opt/python/lib/python3.12/site-packages/oracledb/init.py)

Not immediately helpful, but for any future readers of these comments, the next version of python-oracledb (2.3) removes circular imports, and should show the base configuration problem. (The commit is here).

Does https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-python-oracle-connection help?

@ChristopherJones thanks for the link, I will look at it as am considering other ways now so painful to be honest even though it looks simple
