# BeautifulSoup installation or alternative without easy_install

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, windows-7-x64

I wanted to write a program to scrape a website from python. Since there is no built-in possibility to do so, I decided to give the BeautifulSoup module a try.

Unfortunately I encountered some problems using pip and ez_install, since I use Windows 7 64 bit and Python 3.3.

Is there a way to get the BeautifulSoup module on my Python 3.3 installation with Windows 7 64x without ez_install or easy_install, since I have too much trouble with this, or is there an alternative module which can be easily installed?

Answer (score 1):

Just download [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/download//) and then add  the `BeautifulSoup.py (uncompress the download tarball file use uncompress soft such as 7z)` to your python sys.path use `sys.path.append("/path/to/BeautifulSoup.py")`, of cource you can just put it under your current src dir as a normal python module or put it in the pathon's sys path.

BTW the tarball install(or build) way is:

```
cd BeautifulSoup
python setup.py install(or build)
```

if you are using **python3**,  you can dowload the `bs4(look at the commetn under this answer)`, just let the `bs4`(in the tarball source dir) under your python's sys path and then

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

good luck~

Comment: Unfortunately it still outputs me the default Python 2 - Python 3 incompatibility errors (like when it uses "print" or "raise")... Is there a version for Python 3 around?

Comment: oh, you need BeautifulSoup4, just donwload [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/) or in the [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add to download it and add it to your python search path directly.  (Which is in sys.path, if you need to check it.)

From the documentation:
Beautiful Soup is licensed under the MIT license, so you can also download the tarball, drop the bs4/ directory into almost any Python application (or into your library path) and start using it immediately. (If you want to do this under Python 3, you will need to manually convert the code using 2to3.)

Comment: Should be able to just do `2to3 -w *.py` which will create backups of the existing Python files, and then overwrite the existing files with the converted code.  If that's not working, drop me a comment with the errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but check out [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) to install python packages. It's supposed to be better.

[Why use pip over easy_install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install)

I have personally used BeautifulSoup and like it. I have heard [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery) is good too with a jquery like interface.